# Create a Pride Flag

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, graphical-output

## Challenge

Create the image of a pride flag (rainbow flag), i.e. a six coloured striped flag (from top to bottom): red, orange, yellow, green, blue, and violet.

## Output

[image]

## Example (R)

```
barplot(rep(1, 6), horiz = TRUE, axes = FALSE, space = 0, border = NA, col = c("darkviolet", "blue", "darkgreen", "yellow", "orange", "red"))
```

## Rules

- The algo should actually create the image, not just load an existing one.
- You may use any colors reasonably recognizable as "red", "orange", "yellow, "green", "blue", and "violet".
- The flag may either be scalable (such as an SVG, or output that scales to window size) or at least size 200px by 300px.
- All coloured areas should be of the same size.

Every answer must include the resulting picture!

Credits: this post was inspired by the following post: [Draw the flag of Tennessee](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/194299/448).

Comment: OK I have reopened this and cleared the comments.  I would still personally prefer if both this question and the linked question actually gave guidelines for colors beyond it just looks right.  But since there is a precedent I think we will just see how it plays out.

Comment: "All coloured areas should be of the same size." What about if the image isn't a multiple of 6 pixels tall?

Answer (score 8):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `sḢ`, 36 bytes

```
`<p «⟇=øḢ-÷¥:#%7;₃ṁ:0>.`»‡Ė\Tµi»Hǒv%
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJz4biiIiwiIiwiYDxwIMKr4p+HPcO44biiLcO3wqU6IyU3O+KCg+G5gTowPi5gwrvigKHEllxcVMK1acK7SMeSdiUiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Stuff Vyxal isn't meant to do! This took far too long. The `Ḣ` flag renders stdout as HTML.

[image]

```
               v  # Over each element of...
     »‡Ė\Tµi»     # A compressed integer
             Hǒ   # Split into chunks of two...
                % # Insert that into...
`...`             # Compresssed string `<p style=background-color:#%7;margin:0>.`
                  # (s flag) turn the result into something HTML understands
                  # (Ḣ flag) render the output as HTML
```

For compression purposes, all the character codes end in 7.

Answer (score 7):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 73 bytes

```
view/tight[style s: box 315x35 below s red s#fa0 s#ff0 s#0f0 s#00f s#808]
```

[image]

Works in Red console. To run as a standalone program, we must add in front:

```
Red[needs view]
```

I don't know, whether this has to be counted.

Comment: I don't think the `Red[]` header has to be counted.

Answer (score 7):

## DOS 80186 .COM executable, <s>31</s> 30 bytes

xxd:

```
00000000: b0 13 cd 10 68 00 a0 07 31 ff be 18 01 ac b9 80  ....h...1.......
00000010: 2a f3 aa 3c 05 75 f6 c3 28 2a 2c 02 20 05        *..<.u..(*,. .
```

Commented assembly:

```lisp
        ; NASM syntax
        [cpu 186]
        [org 0x100]
start:
        ; Set DOS to mode 13h for 320x200, 256 colors
        ; Since we know the DOS startup state, we can just set AL.
        mov     al, 0x13 ; 0x0013
        int     0x10
        ; Set ES to point to the video ram segment
        push    0xa000
        pop     es
        ; Set DI to point to the start of video ram
        xor     di, di
        ; Set SI to our lookup table
        mov     si, colors
.loop:
        ; Load color from lookup table
        lodsb
        ; Roughly 1/6 of the screen
        ; ceil(200 / 6) * 320
        mov     cx, 10880
        ; For all CX iterations, store byte to video ram
        rep     stosb
        ; Check for last byte in lut and loop if it is not
        ; that.
        cmp     al, 5
        jnz     .loop
.ret:
        ; Return to DOS, leaving a pretty but annoying flag on
        ; the screen that requires a manual mode reset.
        ret
 
        ; Lookup table for the default 256 color palette.
colors:
        ;   R   O   Y   G   B   P
        db 40, 42, 44,  2, 32,  5
```

I'm not sure if this is valid, as the last stripe is technically a bit shorter than the others, but 200 is not a multiple of 6 so it is unavoidable at this size.

Screenshot (the `C:\CODE>` part is simply the DOS prompt overwriting it after exiting)

[image]

- 1 byte: `stosb` already stores to the `es` segment. What a dummy.

Answer (score 5):

### Postscript, 42 bytes

Hand tokenised (42 bytes including showpage, 40 bytes without).

```
00000000: 36 88 09 32 5b 30 20 2e 31 92 38 30 88 f7 88 f7  6..2[0 .1.80....
00000010: 5d 7b 8e 05 88 33 3c e3 00 7d 8d 00 33 20 63 6f  ]{...3<..}..3 co
00000020: 6c 6f 72 69 6d 61 67 65 92 a1                    lorimage..
```

No tokenisation (62 bytes including showpage, 53 bytes without):

```
6 9 2[0 .1 .1 0 -9 -9]{<88333ce30>}false 3 colorimage
showpage
```

This renders to about 3.2 by 2.1 cm (0.8" by 1.25"). The size is limited by the constants '.1'. Making the flag bigger requires a smaller number which will need one extra byte (two bytes in the untokenised version).

The tokenised version is the same as the untokenised version except the ".1 .1" is encoded as ".1 dup" to save a byte.

[image: GSView window redering Postscript pride flag]

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first answer.

Answer (score 4):

## <s>SVG, 254 bytes</s> HTML, <s>181</s> <s>173</s> 165 bytes

By moving from SVG to HTML, I can get away with not specifying a bunch of things and leaving some tags open.

- Saved ~ 70 bytes thanks to Wheat Wizard.
- Saved 8 + 8 bytes thanks to pxeger.

```html
<svg><rect y=0 fill=red /><rect y=1 fill=#fa0 /><rect y=2 fill=#ff0 /><rect y=3 fill=#4f0 /><rect y=4 fill=blue /><rect y=5 fill=#808><style>rect{width:8px;height:1px
```

After zooming in a lot, you can see

[image]

Comment: I don't think you need the `xmlns`.  There should be a tips for golfing in SVG somewhere.

Comment: And technically speaking since SVG is scalable you shouldn't need the viewbox either.  It will just look really tiny, but you can scale it up.

Comment: Well, you are more or less right, I guess. If I remove the xmlns, then I think the SVG no longer works as a standalone SVG file (at least not on my browsers) but I can change the file to an HTML file, and then removing `xmlns` and `viewBox` are just fine.

Comment: And I don't think you need quotes for a lot of things.  The numbers at least you can get by with the quotes removed.  I'd have to check on colors.

Comment: @WheatWizard I shaved a considerable amount of bytes with your input and also leaving a bunch of tags open :P

Comment: Please post the resulting picture as specified above, thank you

Comment: @vonjd done, although you could hit the "run code snippet" button and see the result for yourself.

Comment: You can replace all the `color="#xxx"/>` with `color=#xxx />`, and you can move the `<style>` to the end which lets you omit the closing tag

Comment: @pxeger is that a "joke", because I have no `color="#xxx"/>`, only `fill="#xxx"/>`, and so you are saying I can safely make 0 substitutions, or are you serious (and made a mistake)? Because, on my browser, I cannot remove the `"` from the hexadecimal colors.

Comment: I meant `fill`, not `color` then. [This](https://t.pxeger.com/xs.html?v=%3Ctextarea%3E%3Csvg%3E%3Crect%20y%3D0%20fill%3Dred+/%3E%3Crect%20y%3D1%20fill%3D%23fa0+/%3E%3Crect%20y%3D2%20fill%3D%23ff0+/%3E%3Crect%20y%3D3%20fill%3D%234f0+/%3E%3Crect%20y%3D4%20fill%3Dblue+/%3E%3Crect%20y%3D5%20fill%3D%23808+%3E%3Cstyle%3Erect{width%3A8px%3Bheight%3A1px}) works for me though (Firefox 90.0b6). Also you can remove the last `}` in the CSS

Comment: @pxeger ah my problem was that I was removing the `"` and then having the colour be immediately next to the `/`, but that's what doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

## [QBasic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QBasic), 78 bytes

```
SCREEN 9
FOR i=0TO 5
READ c
LINE(0,i*40)-(400,239),c,BF
NEXT
DATA 4,6,14,2,9,5
```

The orange looks more like brown, in my opinion, but it's the closest QBasic has (it's the dark version of yellow). Here's the output when run on DOSBox at [Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/msdos_qbasic_megapack):

[image: QBasic flag output]

Answer (score 4):

## Nim, <strike>862</strike> <strike>274</strike> 246 bytes

```
var
  y=33.0
  m=newImage(297,198)
  c=newContext(m)
  r=y/2
for i in 0..5:c.strokeStyle="#FF5C00#FF8C00#FFE900#006400#00008B#4B0082"[i*7..i*7+6];c.lineWidth=y;c.strokeSegment(segment(vec2(0,r),vec2(y*9,r)));r+=y;m.writeFile("l.png")
```

Using the Nim library pixie. If you have Nim and Nimble installed, a quick `nimble install pixie` should let you run it perfectly! It outputs to l.png. I am inexperienced with Pixie and Nim, so if I did anything wrong, please let me know. This answer has gone through a lot of revisions, from totally un-golfy to fairly golfed. Bytes were counted using `wc -c`.

[image: An image of the pride flag created by my code.]

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first answer.

Comment: I'm guessing that the 4 space indent on each line is a formatting error, not part of the code, so I've removed it. Feel free to rollback if this is in error :)

Comment: Yes, the indent was accidental. I will edit it.

Answer (score 4):

## C, 69 bytes

I don't have comment privileges yet, so I'm adding this as another answer. This is an improvement on @weirdsmiley's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230635/103498).

```cpp
#define p(s)puts("\e["#s"m█");
main(){p(91)p(31)p(93)p(32)p(34)p(35)}
```

[Try it on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Tj1bbvece)

I added the the `\e[` and `m` to the `p` macro because it was used 6 times in each macro invocation. Also the `\e[0m` (which resets the color) can be removed because the color is overwritten again before each `puts`.

If there was a way to make the `91` and `93` start with a `3`, then it might save a few bytes by being able to remove the `3` from the 30s.

I'm new to codegolf, so I'm sure if this is 69 or more bytes (because of the `█` character).

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3 with `pygame`, <strike>166</strike> 152 bytes

I wrote this before realizing there was another pygame answer here, but I'm still posting it because I wrote it independently, and it does use a rather different method for getting the colors.

```python
from pygame import*
d=display
s=d.set_mode()
for i in range(6):
 draw.rect(s,("red","orange","yellow","green","blue","purple")[i],(0,i*3,32,3))
d.flip()
```

Edit -14 bytes: Some golfing I did on [another pygame answer I just posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/245337/111305) helped me golf this one too.

New output:

[image: A mostly black screen with a very small rainbow flag in the top left]

As the size makes this almost illegible, here's a scaled up version (from the older code, hence the window bar at the top) for better viewing:

[image: A window displaying a 6-stripe pride flag]

Answer (score 4):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 75 bytes

```
k=255
C=rgb([k,k,k,0,0,75],[0,165,k,k,0,0],[0,0,0,0,k,k])
[5...0]<y<[6...1]
```

Result:
[image]

Technically, each colored bar has the same area of infinity, but if that's not allowed, then you can simply add a domain restriction at the end of the inequality with the cost of some additional bytes.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wzrjggyt5s)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/egir8k9sqz)

There must be some way to golf that huge `rgb()` expression, but I don't see a way at the moment...

---

### Bonus Answer, 5 bytes

```
pride
```

If you paste `pride` into an empty expression, Desmos will automatically redirect you to a graph of the pride flag.

You have a chance of getting this graph:
[image]

Or this graph:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

## TikZ, 164 bytes

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}\begin{document}\tikz{\foreach\u\c in{1/purple,2/blue,3/green,4/yellow,5/orange,6/red}{\fill[\c](,\u)rectangle(9,7);}}\end{document}
```

Pretty simple.

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}\begin{document}\tikz{ % boilerplate
% For every color and index ascending from the bottom.
\foreach\u\c in{1/purple,2/blue,3/green,4/yellow,5/orange,6/red}{
   % Draw a filled rectangle in that color from (0,u) to the upper right corner
   \fill[\c](,\u)rectangle(9,7);
}
}\end{document} %boilerplate
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I think the last color should be "violet". While I agree that the OP does not properly specify how the colors should be displayed, it looks more reddish to me.

Comment: @RecursiveCo. tikz calls that color purple, so IMO it's purple.  It looks different from the flag, but it definitely still looks purple.

Comment: I would say the green on my flag looks even more different from the provided flag, than the difference between the purples.

Comment: Ok, that's fine! Also note your PFP looks like the pride flag. ;)

Comment: @RecursiveCo. Hmm, it does look somewhat like the pride flag, what a coincidence. Definitely couldn't be because it's June. :P

Comment: 141 bytes: `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}\document\tikz{\foreach[count=\u]~in{violet,blue,green,yellow,orange,red}{\fill[~](,\u)rectangle(9,7);}}\stop`

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3 + Turtle, 183 bytes

```
from turtle import*
for x in "red orange yellow green blue violet".split():fillcolor(x);begin_fill();exec("fd(200);lt(90);fd(20);lt(90);"*2);end_fill();rt(90);fd(20);lt(90)
mainloop()
```

[image]

The turtle pointer by default starts at cartesian coordinates (0,0) so the image is in the 4<sup>th</sup> quadrant.

Comment: You're gonna get mad at me for this, but I have a pygame answer ready.

Comment: @RecursiveCo. never mind. Go post it!

Comment: How long is your answer in pygame?

Comment: @RecursiveCo. is not ready yet

Comment: You can post yours if it's less than 174 bytes long (my length)

Comment: @RecursiveCo. go post it I am too lazy to make one now

Comment: Save yourself some bytes by using `"f00 fa0 ff0 4f0 00f 808".split():fillcolor("#"+x)` instead of `"red orange yellow green blue violet".split():fillcolor(x)`

Comment: You can remove the space between "in" and the string literal.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/), <s>142</s> 139 bytes

```
BarChart[1~Table~6,BarOrigin->Left,ChartStyle->{Purple,Blue,Green,Yellow,Orange,Red},BarSpacing->0,Axes->0>1,ChartBaseStyle->EdgeForm@None]
```

`ChartBaseStyle->EdgeForm@None` removes the faint black lines that would normally separate each bar.

-3 bytes thanks to att.

[image]

Comment: `False`->`0>1`, `EdgeForm[None]`->`EdgeForm@None`

Comment: @att Thanks, appreciate the assist.  I've admired many of your clever MMA golfs.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>108</s> <s>89</s> <s>85</s> 80 bytes

```python
print("P3 300 204 9")
for x in range(6):print(*"900960990070009707"[x::6]*10200)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQynAWMHYwEDByMBEwVJJkystv0ihQiEzT6EoMS89VcNM0wqiTkvJ0sDA0szAEkiZGwCZ5gbmStEVVlZmsVqGBkYGBpr//wMA)

*Huge change (-22 chars) thanks to ovs, and -5 more from Wheat Wizard!*

The output is an ASCII PPM image file, which is easy to generate but incredibly inefficient space-wise.  So even at 300x204 pixels it's too larger for TIO, so it's truncated if you run the code there.

Here's an explanation.

```python
print("P3 300 204 9")                        # Print the PPM header (1)
for x in range(6): ...                       # For each distinct color
... print(*"900960990070009707"[x::6]*10200) # Print 10200 copies of the RGB value (2)
```

(1) - `P3` means it's an RGB image, `300 204` are the dimensions and the last number if the max RGB value `9` in this case so that we can use single digit values.

(2) - The RGB values are single byte since the color depth in the header is given as `9`.  The string `900960990070009707` holds the 3 digit RGB values for each of the 6 rows.

The image uploader won't accept a PPM file so I loaded it into GIMP and exported it as a PNG to include it.

[image]

Comment: And if you reorder the color string, `[x//10200*3:][:3]` can be shortened to `[x//10200::6]`

Comment: Nice idea to use the `*` unpacking in the print line.  I never thought of that...

Comment: [This should save 5 bytes.](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQynAWMHYwEDByMBEwVJJkystv0ihQiEzT6EoMS89VcNM0wqiTkvJ0sDA0szAEkiZGwCZ5gbmStEVVlZmsVqGBkYGBpr//wMA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Great idea to make the loop print all the RGB's for a given color and not just one pixel, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [K (oK) + `iKe`](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 79 bytes

```
w:300
h:200
{(0,x*34;,("red";"#fa0";"#ff0";"#0f0";"#00f";"#808")x;(34;w)#0)}'!6
```

[Try it online!](https://johnearnest.github.io/ok/ike/ike.html?key=CPMZdZ5W)

Draws a static bitmap with 300x200px area.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>91</s> 57 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

The latest entry in my series of making Japt do things it shouldn't be able to do!

```
Ol"%c "²³$,...$`fÇÛÆèÆÇ¾b`roT ò3 Ëi`padÜA:2%26%;baå®":#
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=JGNvbnNvbGUuY2xlYXIoJA&code=T2wiJWMgIrKzJCwuLi4kYGbH28boxsePvmJgcm9UIPIzIMtpYHBhZNxBOjIlMjYlO2Jh5a4iEDoj) (Open your browser's console. Only tested in Chrome.)

### Original solution

```
$flags$
`fÇÛÆèÆÇ¾b`roT ò3 £$V.before(V.cloneNode(),V.style.border=V.style.background='#'+X
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=JGZsYWdzLnBhcmVudE5vZGUuY2xhc3NMaXN0LnJlbW92ZSgiY29sbGFwc2VkIikk&code=JGZsYWdzJApgZsfbxujGx4%2b%2bYmByb1Qg8jMgoyRWLmJlZm9yZShWLmNsb25lTm9kZSgpLFYuc3R5bGUuYm9yZGVyPVYuc3R5bGUuYmFja2dyb3VuZD0nIycrWA)

Comment: +1 for putting the flag in `Flags`.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript - 165 bytes

The snippet works in the console.

```js
console.log(...["red","orange","#ff0","green","#00f","violet"].reduce((a,c)=>{a[0]=a[0]+'%c0';return [...a,`background:${c};color:${c};padding:35px 400px;`];},['']))
```

[image]

#### EDIT:

Used Chrome Version 91.0.4472.114 (Official Build) (x86_64) for creating the image.

Comment: Is this browser/version dependent? If yes, better specify it. In Firefox 88.0 looks a bit different: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQnLo.png

Comment: @manatwork thanks for drawing my attention to this. I wasn't expecting browser dependency.

Comment: After some investigation, it looks like Firefox defaults to display:inline and Chrome/Edge _forces_ inline-block (ignoring any display we specify). Putting display:inline-block makes both the same (but for golf, display:block is shorter). After some experimentation, my best cross-browser is then `console.log(...["f00","f80","ff0","0f0","00f","808"].reduce((a,c)=>{a[0]+='%c ';return[...a,\`background:#${c};display:block;padding:2%26%\`]},['']))` For just Firefox we can remove the padding, for just Chrome/Edge we can remove the display.

Answer (score 3):

## Swift + UIKit, 216 bytes

A function that returns a `UIView`.

```swift
func f()->UIView{let v=UIStackView(arrangedSubviews:[UIColor]([.red,.orange,.yellow,.green,.blue,.purple]).map{let v=UIView()
v.backgroundColor=$0
return v})
v.axis = .vertical
v.distribution = .fillEqually
return v}
```

You can't remove the whitespace around the last two `=` operators.

Result when displayed at full screen on iPhone Xʀ:

[image: 1]

## Swift + SwiftUI, 90 bytes

A `View`. Not a function that returns one -- you could say `let prideFlag = /* the answer */`, or include the answer directly in a ViewBuilder.

```swift
VStack(spacing:0){Color.red
Color.orange
Color.yellow
Color.green
Color.blue
Color.purple}
```

*This is why everyone prefers SwiftUI.*

The colors are slightly different, and it doesn't let itself extend into the margins at the top/bottom of the screen, but the result is very similar:

[image: 2]

Answer (score 2):

## Pygame, 171 bytes

```py
from pygame import*
d=display
e=99
s=d.set_mode((e*9,e*6))
m=[255]
l=[0]
i=0
for c in[m+l*2,m+[e]+l,m*2+l,l+m+l,l+l+m,[e,0,e]]:draw.rect(s,c,(0,i*e,e*9,e));i+=1
d.update()
```

Here's the flag generated:
[image]

Comment: `l=[0];i=0` can be `l=i,=[0]` (and possibly you can use `255,` `0,` `(e,)` instead of `[255]` `[0]` `[e]`, but I can't test that easily atm)

Comment: @pxeger Thanks! How does the `,=` trick work? And also `(e,)` should be placed where?

Comment: It's `l = (i,) = [0]`; the `i` is unpacked from the list. The `(e,)`  should go in place of `[e]` in `m+[e]+l`

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>171 bytes</s> <s>118 bytes</s> 100 bytes

EDIT: Saved 53 bytes thanks to [Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/wheat-wizard) and 14 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

```
#define p(s) printf(#s"█\e[0m\n");
main(){p(\e[91m)p(\e[31m)p(\e[93m)p(\e[32m)p(\e[34m)p(\e[35m)}
```

Try on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/PnGbGzcrx)!

NOTE: Output differs a little according to Godbolt's UI.

Here is the output from my native machine.

[image]

Comment: Since the challenge has no required aspect ration you can save length by just using 1 `█`.

Comment: Ahh! That's good news!

Comment: I also got to learn that having a return type is not necessary in --C90!

Comment: Suggest `p(s)puts(#s"█\e[0m")` instead of `p(s) printf(#s"█\e[0m\n")`

Answer (score 2):

## R + ggplot2,150 bytes - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/index.html

```
library(ggplot2);ggplot(data.frame(y=1:6),aes(y=y))+theme_void()+geom_bar(fill=c("#9400D3","#0000FF","#006400","#FFFF00","#FFA500","#FF0000"),width=1)
```

the output image
[image]

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 107 bytes

```js
console.log(`%c `.repeat(6),...`f00fa0ff00f000fb0b`.match(/.../g).map(c=>`background:#${c};padding:2%26%`))
```

Open your browser's console and run the snippet below.

```js
console.clear()
console.log(`%c `.repeat(6),...`f00fa0ff00f000fb0b`.match(/.../g).map(c=>`background:#${c};padding:2%26%`))
```

Comment: `console.log(`\n%c`.padEnd(99).repeat(6),...`f00fa0ff00f000fb0b`.match(/.../g).map(c=>`background:#${c}`))`?

Answer (score 2):

## [Big Unicorn](https://www.theedkins.co.uk/jo/games/unicorn/bigunicorn/index.htm), 54 bytes

```
C1P9T1P2T1C7P9T3P2C2T3P9T1P2T1C9P9T3P2T3C3P9T1P2T1C8P9
```

Unicorns sure do love rainbows...

[image: pride flag on grid of white]

Answer (score 2):

## [`dc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dc_(computer_program)) + [QOI](https://qoiformat.org/), 116 bytes

```
16i[qoif]P0dPP1P32P0ddPPPCCP3P0P5AP[A7[FDP1-d0<R]dsRxF0Pk]ddddddxFEPFFP80P0PxFEPFFdPP0Px7APx6DPx5APx0ddddddPPPPPPP1P
```

Outputs a 306x204 image to stdout in the [Quite OK Image Format](https://qoiformat.org) (shown here converted to png):

[image: Pride flag output]

QOI images can be viewed with ImageMagick, among other software:

```
dc -e"16i[qoif]P0dPP1P32P0ddPPPCCP3P0P5AP[A7[FDP1-d0<R]dsRxF0Pk]ddddddxFEPFFP80P0PxFEPFFdPP0Px7APx6DPx5APx0ddddddPPPPPPP1P" | magick display
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org/), 52 bytes

```
⍉⍉↯400⍉⬚50▽[]÷4[4_0_0 4_2_0 4_4_0 0_4_0 0_0_4 3_0_4]
```

[Try it online!](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=4o2J4o2J4oavNDAw4o2J4qyaNTDilr1bXcO3NFs0XzBfMCA0XzJfMCA0XzRfMCAwXzRfMCAwXzBfNCAzXzBfNF0=)

```
               ÷4[4_0_0 4_2_0 4_4_0 0_4_0 0_0_4 3_0_4]   # Set up the colours 
                                                           (RGB values between 0 and 1)
         ⬚50▽[]                                          # Make an array of 50 of each RGB value
       ⍉                                                # Transpose the array
   ↯400                                                  # Repeat each element 400 times 
⍉⍉                                                     # Transpose to the correct format
                                                          (300x400x3)
```

[image: Pride flag made in Uiua language]

A couple of bytes can be saved by making the image 40px by 30px. This can be done by removing a zero from each of "400" and "50" in the code above.

However, the result is not great:
[image: Tiny pride flage made in Uiua]

Answer (score 1):

## HTML, <s>330</s> 245 bytes

Saved 7 bytes thanks to Wheat Wizard!

Saved 78 bytes thanks to Recursive Co.!

```html
<div style="background:red">&nbsp;</div><div style="background:#F60">&nbsp;</div><div style="background:#CF0">&nbsp;</div><div style="background:#0F0">&nbsp;</div><div style="background:blue">&nbsp;</div><div style="background:#C0F">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: For basically every color other than `red` and `blue` the hex is going to be shorter. e.g. `#f80` is shorter than `orange`

Comment: @WheatWizard Thanks, I didn't realize you could use 3 character hex codes!

Comment: Bytesavings: remove doctype, all `&nbsp;`s, shortening background-colors to background, using hex codes with single letters, removing quotes and using `/>` to close tags, and no need for the html and body tags.

Comment: @RecursiveCo. Thanks! I tried making the `div`s empty before, but they don't show up without text inside them, for some reason.

Comment: Please post the resulting picture as specified above, thank you

Comment: @vonjd just click "run code snippet"

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>80</s> <s>65</s> 45 bytes

```r
image(t(1:6),c=rainbow(12)[c(10,8,4:1)],ax=F)
```

[Try it at rdrr.io!](https://rdrr.io/snippets/embed/?code=image(t(1%3A6)%2Cc%3Drainbow(12)%5Bc(10%2C8%2C4%3A1)%5D%2Cax%3DF))

**Original 80-byte version**

```r
plot(0,,,1:2,c(1,7),,,,"","",,F);rect(1,7:2,2,6:1,,,rainbow(12)[c(1:4,8,10)],NA)
```

[Try it at rdrr.io!](https://rdrr.io/snippets/embed/?code=plot(0%2C%2C%2C1%3A2%2Cc(1%2C7)%2C%2C%2C%2C%22%22%2C%22%22%2C%2CF)%3Brect(1%2C7%3A2%2C2%2C6%3A1%2C%2C%2Crainbow(12)%5Bc(1%3A4%2C8%2C10)%5D%2CNA)%0A)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [ConTeXt](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Main_Page), 112 bytes

It produces PDF, hence scalable, output:

```tex
\startMPpage for i=0upto5:draw(0,-i)--(5,-i)withcolor hsvtorgb(i*(25+6i),1,1)withpen pensquare;endfor\stopMPpage
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## HTML & CSS — 207 bytes

[image]

```css
hr{height:30px;margin:0;border:0}hr{background:red}*+hr{background:orange}*+*+hr{background:yellow}*+*+*+hr{background:green}*+*+*+*+hr{background:blue}*+*+*+*+*+hr{background:violet}
```

```html
<hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr>
```

Comment: You can change all but last `hr` in each sequence with `*`, like `*+*+*+*+*+hr{background:violet}`. You can save some bytes by writing the entire CSS in one line.

Comment: @manatwork Wow... Didn't know that ;) You helped me saved 15 bytes! Thanks!

Comment: You can change _all_ the `hr`s in the CSS to `*`. Also, other than `red` & `blue`, using 3 digit hex values for the colours will be shorter.

Comment: -1 bytes by replacing `30px` with `2em`

Answer (score 1):

## [Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu), 289 bytes

```
when gf clicked
add(16753920)to[l v
add(16776960)to[l v
add(65280)to[l v
add(255)to[l v
add(8388736) to [l v
set pen color to(()+(16711680
set pen size to(800
pen down
repeat(5
change[a v] by (1
go to x:(-240)y:((150)-((60)*(a
set pen size to(60
set pen color to(item(a)of[l v
set x to(240
```

[image: Code image]

[Try it online!](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/710926486/) | [Test it on Scratchblocks!](http://scratchblocks.github.io/#?style=scratch3&script=when%20gf%20clicked%0Aadd(16753920)to%5Bl%20v%0Aadd(16776960)to%5Bl%20v%0Aadd(65280)to%5Bl%20v%0Aadd(255)to%5Bl%20v%0Aadd(8388736)%20to%20%5Bl%20v%0Aset%20pen%20color%20to(()%2B(16711680%0Aset%20pen%20size%20to(800%0Apen%20down%0Arepeat(5%0Achange%5Ba%20v%5D%20by%20(1%0Ago%20to%20x%3A(-240)y%3A((150)-((60)*(a%0Aset%20pen%20size%20to(60%0Aset%20pen%20color%20to(item(a)of%5Bl%20v%0Aset%20x%20to(240)

Comment: Same code, but without 4 spaces: http://scratchblocks.github.io/#?style=scratch3&script=when%20gf%20clicked%0Aadd(16753920)to%5Bl%20v%0Aadd(16776960)to%5Bl%20v%0Aadd(65280)to%5Bl%20v%0Aadd(255)to%5Bl%20v%0Aadd(8388736)to%5Bl%20v%0Aset%20pen%20color%20to(()%2B(16711680%0Aset%20pen%20size%20to(800%0Apen%20down%0Arepeat(5%0Achange%5Ba%20v%5Dby(1%0Ago%20to%20x%3A(-240)y%3A((150)-((60)*(a%0Aset%20pen%20size%20to(60%0Aset%20pen%20color%20to(item(a)of%5Bl%20v%0Aset%20x%20to(240

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 26 bytes

```
„P3ƵÈDY•2Ûm¤Ç{wÕ•3ôŽwÓ×S»»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATYAyf9vc2FiaWX//@KAnlAzxrXDiERZ4oCiMsObbcKkw4d7d8OV4oCiM8O0xb13w5PDl1PCu8K7//8) Outputs as a plain PPM.

## Output

[image: Pride flag]

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, <s>191</s> 187 bytes

```java
import java.awt.*;v->new Frame(){public void paint(Graphics g){for(int i=0;i<6;g.fillRect(0,i++*35+30,300,35))g.setColor(new Color(i<3?255:i/5*143,i==1?200:i/2%2*255,i/4*255));}{show();}}
```

Result:

[image]

**Explanation:**

```java
import java.awt.*;        // Required import for Frame/Graphics/Color
v->                       // Method with empty unused parameter and Frame return
  new Frame(){            //  Create a Frame (window for graphical output)
    public void paint(Graphics g){
                          //   Overwrite its default paint method:
      for(int i=0;i<6     //    Loop `i` in the range [0,6):
          ;               //      After every iteration:
           g.fillRect(    //       Draw the rectangle
             0,i++*35+30, //       at x,y position 0,35i+30, where the `+30` is
                          //       to account for the title-bar
             300,35))     //       of 300 pixels wide and 35 pixels high
                          //       (so the entire flag is 300x210)
       g.setColor(new Color(i<3?255:i/5*143,i==1?200:i/2%2*255,i/4*255));}
                          //     Change the RGB-color based on `i`:
                          //      i=0 (red):    255,  0,  0
                          //      i=1 (orange): 255,200,  0
                          //      i=2 (yellow): 255,255,  0
                          //      i=3 (green):    0,255,  0
                          //      i=4 (blue):     0,  0,255
                          //      i=5 (violet): 143,  0,255
  {                       //   And in an inner initializer block:
   show();}}              //    Show the frame
```

Answer (score 0):

## Batch, 71 bytes

```
@set n=m█^&@echo ␛[m
@echo ␛[31%n%␛[33%n%␛[93%n%␛[32%n%␛[34%n%␛[35%n%
```

`␛` represents the nonprintable  character.

Answer (score 0):

## GameBoy Color machine code, 323 bytes

```
00000000  22 0d 20 fc c9 1f 00 1f  02 ff 03 e0 03 00 7c 10  |". ...........|.|
00000010  40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |@...............|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000100  3e 88 e0 68 1e 06 2e 05  2a e0 69 2a e0 69 f0 68  |>..h....*.i*.i.h|
00000110  c6 06 e0 68 1d 20 f1 3e  01 e0 4f 11 06 20 21 00  |...h. .>..O.. !.|
00000120  98 4a c7 3c 1d 20 fa 76  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.J.<. .v........|
00000130  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000140  00 00 00 c0                                       |....|
00000144
```

The code could be a lot shorter, but a Gameboy ROM needs the value `0xC0` at byte `0x143` to indicate it's a GameBoy Color ROM. The ROM only works on Gearboy.

While the GBC only had screen resolution of 160 x 144 pixels, Gearboy quadruples it by default, so that each pixel is 4 times as large.

The binary was generated from this assembler code:

```
; ONLY WORKS ON GEARBOY

DEF rVBK EQU $ff4f
DEF rBCPS EQU $ff68
DEF rBCPD EQU $ff69

SECTION "Rst $0", ROM0[$0]

; @param a value
; @param hl pointer
; @param c count
MemsetSmall::
    ld [hli], a
    dec c
    jr nz, MemsetSmall
    ret

SECTION "Data", ROM0[$5]
Colors:
    ; 15-bit RGB values
    ;   BBBBB GGGGG RRRRR
    DW %00000_00000_11111
    DW %00000_10000_11111
    DW %00000_11111_11111
    DW %00000_11111_00000
    DW %11111_00000_00000
    DW %10000_00000_10000


SECTION "Entrypoint",ROM0[$100]
Entrypoint:
    ; set background palette
    ld a, %10001000
    ldh [rBCPS], a

    ld e, 6
    ld l, LOW(Colors)
.load_color
    ld a, [hli]
    ldh [rBCPD], a
    ld a, [hli]
    ldh [rBCPD], a
    ; skip other 3 colors of this palette
    ldh a, [rBCPS]
    add 6
    ldh [rBCPS], a
    
    dec e
    jr nz, .load_color

    ld a, 1
    ldh [rVBK], a

    ld de, (32 << 8) | 6
    ld hl, $9800

.draw_stripe
    ld c, d
    rst MemsetSmall
    inc a

    dec e
    jr nz, .draw_stripe

    halt


SECTION "HEADER", ROM0[$0143]
    DB $c0
```

[image: screenshot from Gearboy]

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 345 bytes

```powershell
$a='System.Windows.Forms'
Add-Type -AssemblyName $a
$Form=New-Object "$a.Form"
$l=0
$c=@('red','orange','yellow','green','blue','indigo')
foreach($s in $c){
$t=New-Object "$a.Label"
$t.Size=New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,10) 
$t.Location=New-Object System.Drawing.Point(0,$l)
$t.BackColor=$s
$form.Controls.Add($t)
$l+=10
}$Form.ShowDialog()
```

[Can't run in the browser](https://tio.run/##fVDBSsQwEL3nK8oykBbb0H5AwXUXT8sqVPCcpmMbTTNLEglV/PaaLh7Eg6d5zHuPN/MuFNH5CY1ZV5At7xYfcBbP2g4UvbgnN3vO9sNQPS0XzKq99zj3ZjnLGTOQDDZFe8ZYPfSvqEK2A3l17RiYtmag2tucOxx4yclJO2ICS4qjmMDoEG2avXnf9ilUj8QL9kIOpZpy8Jm2Gajik0H4m3KSPZoUE0SnP/A3@/PE0cmo7Xil86auy6Yusk1/IiWDJvuP55G0DXldgik2x51Ubwcy5FrwDNJ5sziQDY6MF6mcHEKSmZu2qdnXtRLRTRSPWhoa82JdvwE)

## Output

[image]

No doubt that this can be improved upon!

Answer (score 0):

## [Easyfuck](https://github.com/Quadruplay/easyfuck/wiki), 28 bytes

```
HúÜ¸ß~¼bSHY\PLDk_.yvCä+APC]PAD)NBHESANBH␁¢
```

<sup>due to lack of unicode representations for c1 control characters, they have been replaced by their superscripted abbreviations</sup>

Decompressed:

```
$>[KF}}<1++H[->.<]H>!.>]@␊08<␌␃"
```

Explanation:

```
$>[KF}}<1++H[->.<]H>!.>]@␊08<␌␃"
$>                               copy 1st cell to storage, move to 2nd
  [                    ]         while loop
   KF}}                          set color according to value of current cell, then set current cell to 60 (█)
       <1++H                     go to previous cell, set it to 18, and change to alternative charpage
            [    ]               while loop
             ->.<                print next cell while decrementing the current one
                  H>             go back to normal charpage, then go to the next cell
                    !.>          set it to storage, print, and move to the next cell
                        @        return
                         ␊08<␌␃" initializer data (new line, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, purple)
```