# Draw the Ukrainian Flag

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, graphical-output

As you probably know, there is a [war going on in Ukraine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_Russian_invasion_of_Ukraine). I noticed that it seems nobody has posted a Ukrainian flag challenge yet, so I thought I'd do it myself in support of Ukraine.

### The Challenge

Here is the flag:
[image: Flag of Ukraine]

- The flag is divided horizontally across the middle into two equally sized stripes.
- Stripe colors: `(0, 87, 183)` or `#0057B7` (blue, top) and `(255, 215, 0)` or `#FFD700` (yellow, bottom).
- Colors must be exact if possible, otherwise use the closest available blue and yellow.
- The image can be saved to a file or piped raw to STDOUT in any common image file format, or it can be displayed in a window.
- The image must be sized at a 3:2 ratio, and at least 78 by 52 pixels.
- Alternatively, output a block of text at least 78 characters wide made of non-whitespace characters that depicts the flag, using [ANSI color codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) to color it. (Use standard blue and yellow.)
- Built-in flag images, flag-drawing libraries, or [horrendously upscaling the Ukrainian flag emoji](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60681392#60681392) are prohibited.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins!

Comment: If the ANSI color code option is chosen, what aspect ratio should we assume each character has?

Comment: @Nitrodon You may assume each character is a square.

Comment: Is some slight error allowed in the stripe colors or does it have to be exact?

Comment: @des54321 It must be exact.

Comment: @Ginger Then taking in mind that (and the QBasic answer already posted), you might want to, for clarity, add a rule along the lines of "Colors must be exact if possible in your language, otherwise the closest blue/yellow available is acceptable"

Comment: @des54321 I agree with this, but I can't really think of a case in which they wouldn't be exact.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding the QBasic answer already posted, I think that answer has inexact colors due to limitations of the language, but it is certainly likely other ancient languages could also have too-limited color-spaces to display the correct colors

Comment: Related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/230438/create-a-pride-flag

Comment: Can we use builtin flag of another country and modify?

Comment: @l4m2 Nope, sorry

Comment: Just pointing out that the yellow in the image above is `#fbd02a` and the blue is `#1a54b2`, as opposed to the `#ffd700` and `#0057b7` specified in the text.

Comment: @SteveBennett Looks like `#ffd600` and `#005bbc` to me. (Still not right, but much closer)

Comment: Interesting, I'm using the eyedropper tool in FF dev tools, which report #fbd02a everywhere.

Comment: When using ANSI color codes on a terminal, why can't I use space and am forced to use a visible character? It will be more visually pleasing to use background color. I can provide command that prints width and height of my output.

Comment: @seshoumara Them's the rules.

Comment: The real flag has a trident at the top left.

Answer (score 86):

## HTML+SVG, 39 bytes

```html
<svg viewbox=12.5,-8.9,1.5,1><text>
```

<s>The question forbids zooming in on the *Ukraine*  flag... but not the flag of Sweden!</s> Apparently that's disallowed too, so I'm using an emoji.

This code is terrible practice and probably doesn't work on most browsers/OSes. It works on Firefox 98 on MacOS 12.2.1, and the emoji itself is very system dependent in its size and layout.

In particular, it doesn't seem to work in a Stack Snippet, so here's something: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuKIiLCIiLCJgPHN2ZyB2aWV3Ym94PTEyLjUsLTguOSwxLjUsMT48dGV4dD7wn5i0IiwiIiwiIl0=)

**Run this at your own risk**, it will severely lag your computer.

Comment: I like this answer... but does it pass the rule that 'Colors must be exact if possible'?

Comment: @Dingus For this approach, it's as close as I've found so far. I tried a *lot* of emoji before I found this one. So I'd say yes.

Comment: Right, but presumably there's a non-emoji way to get the exact colours in HTML+SVG. Whether the rule applies on a per-approach or per-language basis isn't really clear though.

Answer (score 42):

## Scratch, 155 bytes

```
when gf clicked
set pen color to(()+(22455
set pen size to(800
pen down
go to x:(-240)y:(-90
set pen size to(180
set pen color to(()+(16766720
set x to(240
```

[image: Code]
[Try it online!](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/662531644) |
[Test it on Scratchblocks!](http://scratchblocks.github.io/#?style=scratch3&script=when%20gf%20clicked%0Aset%20pen%20color%20to(()%2B(22455%0Aset%20pen%20size%20to(800%0Apen%20down%0Ago%20to%20x%3A(-240)y%3A(-90%0Aset%20pen%20size%20to(180%0Aset%20pen%20color%20to(()%2B(16766720%0Aset%20x%20to(240)

## Explanation

So basically:

1. When the green flag is clicked, the program sets the pen color to `()+(22455)`, because the `set pen color to` block doesn't support bare numbers, so we have to do:
   `[nothing, evaluates to 0]+22455`
   `22455` is the [Scratch color value](https://en.scratch-wiki.info/wiki/Computer_Colors) of `RGB(0, 87, 183)` (blue).
2. Then the pen size is set to `800`, which is just a big number
3. After executing `pen down`, the pencil goes to `x:-240`, which is the leftmost pixel, and to `y:-90` (the starting point for the bottom part). As it goes, the pencil draws a big blue blob which fills out the entire screen.
4. The pen size is set to `180`, half of the window height.
5. The pen color is set to `()+(16766720`, the scratch color value for `RGB(255, 215, 0)` (yellow).
6. Finally, with setting x to `240`, the program draws the bottom "line".

Comment: wow scratch!! I think this is the first time I've seen this language on PPCG :P

Comment: @des54321 I think there have been quite a few before

Comment: @des54321 there have been [quite a few](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aa%20scratch) scratch answers before

Answer (score 32):

## CSS, <s>78</s> <s>75</s> <s>74</s> 71 bytes

```css
*>*{width:9em;border-top:3em solid #0057B7;border-bottom:3em solid gold
```

Edit: Saved 3 bytes by using @pxeger's observation that `gold` is `#FFD700`. Saved 1 byte thanks to @RickN. Saved 3 bytes thanks to @IsmaelMiguel.

Comment: blue is on top not yellow.

Comment: It seems to still render fine with `*>*` which is one byte less than `body`. That will also style the (implicit) `head` tag and its contents, but those are not visible.

Comment: Instead of `78px`, use `9em`, and instead of `26px` use `3em`. This should give you a 9em X 6em flag. Which is a 3:2 ratio and larger in screen size AND saves 3 bytes.

Comment: You can remove the space in `solid #0057B7`.

Answer (score 21):

## [Python 3](https://www.python.org), <s>53</s> <s>51</s> <s>45</s> 42¹ bytes

(+2 bytes if you want to use the Full Block Unicode Character `█` instead of `X`)

¹ *saved 3 bytes thanks to @pxeger*

```
x="\x1b[3%dm"+("\n"+"X"*78)*13;print(x%4,x%3)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3tSpslaSjjVVTcpW0NZRi8pS0lSKUtMwtNLUMja0LijLzSjQqVE10KlSNNSE6oBphBgAA)

Nicer alternative that uses background colors instead of foreground colors:

```
x="\x1b[4%dm"+("\n"+" "*78)*13;print(x%4+x%3)
```

Note that this solution is not valid since it uses spaces.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3tSpslaSjTVRTcpW0NZRi8pS0lRSUtMwtNLUMja0LijLzSjQqVE20K1SNNSE6oBphBgAA)

Here, the programs are represented with 3 more bytes, since the byte `\x1b` does not get rendered (see ATOs).

On my terminal 13 rows seems to be the appropriate height, but it may vary.

Comment: If each character is a pixel I think you want `26` rather than `13`. Also I *think* the escape could go in front of every newline, so `x=("\033[3%dm\n"+"X"*78)*26;print(x%4,x%3)` (does that work?).

Comment: You can remove the `0` in the `\033`. In fact, you can include the character itself in the string verbatim: https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3tSpslaSjjVVTcpW0NZRi8pS0lSKUtMwtNLUMja0LijLzSjQqVE10KlSNNSE6oBphBgAA

Comment: @JonathanAllan it does not work because `x` would contain 26 escape sequences `%d`. For the height, I didn't consider each character as a pixel, but I tried to respect the aspect ratio. Anyway, it does not change much for the code-golf

Comment: Ah, yep `%d` >.< nice answer anyway :D

Answer (score 21):

## Excel VBA, <sub><s>84</s></sub> 66 Bytes

Anonymous function that takes no input and outputs to the range `A1:NH830`. Cell sizes are not adjusted, rather the cell that are selected are adjusted to account for the \$\approx415:124\$ [default cell aspect ratio](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138127/61846).

```vb
[A1:NH830].Interior.Color=55265:[A1:NH415].Interior.Color=12015360
```

### Output

[image: slava ukraini]

Comment: You can use `&HB75700` instead of `12015360` for the same number of bytes.

Answer (score 21):

## HTML + SVG + CSS, <s>73</s> <s>70</s> <s>68</s> 66 bytes

```html
<svg width=225 style=background:linear-gradient(#0057B7+50%,gold+0
```

**Explanation:**

- As a *replaced element*, the `<svg>` element in HTML defaults to dimensions of `300px x 150px`
- Setting `width="225"` gives the `<svg>` a width/height ratio of `225px / 150px` or `3 / 2`

**Update 1:** *Another 3 bytes sliced off after @pxeger's suggestions on how to abuse the HTML even further.*

**Update 2:** *A further 2 bytes shaved off thanks to @cornonthecob's ideas on how to strip from the HTML any vestige of its remaining self-respect.*

**Update 3:** *2 more bytes removed thanks to @Sphinxxx's excellent observation that `gold` may be followed by the value `0` (or anything less than `50%`) without visibly altering the `linear-gradient background`.*

Comment: With some more abuse of HTML you can save 3 bytes: `<svg width=225 style="background:linear-gradient(#0057B7 50%,gold 50%"` (removing the quotes around `225`, and omitting the closing `)` and `>`)

Comment: You can abuse HTML even further by replacing the spaces in the `style` attribute with `+` and then you can remove the quotes: `<svg width=225 style=background:linear-gradient(#0057B7+50%,gold+50%`

Comment: Another 2 bytes: Have the `gold` start at 0 (anything less than 50% will give you the desired sharp gradient). `<svg width=225 style=background:linear-gradient(#0057B7+50%,gold+0`

Comment: Thank you, @Sphinxxx. Your observation seems obvious in hindsight, but it wasn't until you mentioned it that it was.

Comment: In Chrome, it doesn’t work without the closing )>

Answer (score 18):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <s>59</s> <s>57</s> <s>54</s> <s>53</s> <s>51</s> 50 bytes

```
x: 99x33 view/tight[below h1 x#0057B7 h1 x#FFD700]
```

[image]

-1 byte thanks to an anonymous user!

-2 more bytes saved by an anonymous user!

-1 again

Answer (score 18):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>56</s> 55 bytes

```
Image@{{{0,29,61}/85},{{1,.843,0}}}~ImageResize~{78,52}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hc5PC4IwGIDx72IQBS/NzabrIKw/lzpFV/HwEssGOUHfi4351Vd6f/jxtEhv0yLZJ8bXB5syXltsjPbepyAOkPPAlAzgPYed2meQhhCmpXmYwX7N5AsFUoR466zTenPu3EDo6Nj3OFYr8CKHQoV6zfRMqgK4yv6ekBIEl7O3LcsFvCBhNU9AchrJJDVj9946ij8)

[image]

- The best I've found using exponentiation, 56 byte:

```
Image@{{{0,.05,.4}},{{1,.62,0}}}^.36~ImageResize~{78,52}
Image@{{{0,.19,.6}},{{1,.77,0}}}^.65~ImageResize~{78,52}
Image@{{{0,.26,.66}},{{1,.81,0}}}^.8~ImageResize~{78,52}
```

- The only valid dimension that can be written in fewer bytes than `{78,52}` is `9{9,6}`.
  If it weren't for `x~f~y` precedence over `xy`, this would have saved one byte.

Comment: You probably do need `43/51` to satisfy "Colors must be exact"

Comment: @att good point. First, from `Image`  [docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Image.html): *Image[data,"type"] can be used to create an image of a specified data type. Values in data are coerced to the specified type by rounding or clipping. By default, "Real32" is assumed.* Hence `43/51` would still be flawed. But aside from this, when Mathematica interprets the data in the output as bytes it yields the correct RGB values. The sense is that, *for Mathematica*, `.843` (along with many other floats) is exactly the value `215` in the 0-255 range of the RGB24 scale.

Comment: Using the first two entries of `ColorData[97]` would be an amusing way to accomplish this. Unfortunately, though, those colors aren't quite right.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Interesting, I was unaware of that function... Maybe there are some flag for which it would do the trick

Comment: Possibly.  I mainly brought it up because the entries of `ColorData[97]` are the default colors for plots in Mathematica, and it happens that the first two of those default colors are blue and yellow(-ish).

Answer (score 18):

## TI-Basic 83, 25  bytes

This is a rather extreme abuse of the "closest color in your language" rule, as the TI-83 Plus' LCD screen is only capable of two colors (black and "white"; white in air-quotes, as the off color is more green than anything), but it beats all the other graphical output answers except [Unicorn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/245404/111305), and I imagine a newer TI calculator with a color display, such as the TI-84 Plus CE, could do it right with almost identical code, but I don't think I can test that, as I don't own any such calculator, and a quick search of the internet didn't find any free emulators.

```
:AxesOff
:Shade(0,10
:Shade(-10,0,-10,10,3,2
```

Edit: @MarcMush pointed out that, per site consensus, I can assume that the graph bounds are already initialized to `ZStandard`, allowing me to trim that, and explained some details of how the calculator's MEM screen displays program bytecounts, revising my bytecount down to 25

### Output:

To make my rules abuse slightly better, I did opt to make the "yellow" half be lightly filled instead of empty. Although this might not technically constitute a solid color, in the context of what a TI-83 can display, I feel like it is closer to yellow than no fill.

[image: A picture of the screen of a TI-83 calculator, with the top half of the screen fully filled in, and the bottom half lightly filled, overall showing a crude approximation of the Ukrainian flag]

Comment: you can remove `ZStandard` (https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/52967/98541) and use `Xmin` instead of `-10`. Also, TI-Basic is [tokenized](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4764/98541). With these optimizations, I get 24 bytes

Comment: @MarcMush good one on removing ZStandard, but I cant seem to find Xmin as something I can put in on my calculator, and I'm aware of TI-Basic's tokenization, my bytecount is directly from my calculator's memory management screen

Comment: Actually I just tried something else, it seems that the bytecount displayed in the MEM screen includes the program's name, as renaming it to `U` instead of the name I had `UKRAINE` dropped the bytecount to 36, suggesting that my bytecount is actually 35

Comment: `Xmin` is in `VARS` > `Window...`

Comment: an empty program is 10 bytes, so I substract 10 bytes from the program size (1-letter name of course), and I get the same program size as other people answering in TI-Basic. That way it will be the same as if you manually count with the [token sizes](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/tokens)

Comment: Ah got it @MarcMush, thank you

Answer (score 17):

### SQL, <s>379</s> <s>346</s> 244 bytes

This uses Microsoft T-SQL in SQL Management Studio's (SSMS) to generate spatial data. This code should work with Oracle's PL-SQL with few changes. Not sure about how it would work with others.

**Updated** with changes to reduce byte count by t-clausen.dk and removed unnecessary spaces and line breaks, though it's not very readable anymore.

```
DECLARE @C INT=1,@ VARCHAR(MAX)='' WHILE @C<32 SELECT @+='|.0,0 .x'+iif(@C=14,'|26,0 x',''), @C+=1 SET @=REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@+'|-26,0 -26?', '|','SELECT CAST(''POLYGON((0 0,78 0,78 '),'x','26?UNION ALL '),'?',',0 0))''AS GEOMETRY)')EXEC(@)
```

**Update** using REPLACE to cut out redundant parts of the strings and removing some extra spaces after commas:

```
DECLARE @C INT = 1,@S VARCHAR(MAX) = '',@G VARCHAR(99)='|1 0,1 .1,0 .1,0 0))'' AS GEOMETRY) G UNION ALL ' 

WHILE @C<=31 --loop is just to cycle through the colors 

BEGIN
    SET @S+=@G  --MERGE SELECT STATEMENTS OF UNVIEWABLE OBJECTS (TOO SMALL) FOR WRONG COLORS 
    IF @C=14 SET @S+='|78 0,78 26,0 26,0 0))'' AS GEOMETRY) UNION ALL '  --ADD TOP OF FLAG IN BLUE
    SET @C+=1   --UPDATE COLOR COUNTER
END
SET @S+='|78 0,78 -26,0 -26,0 0))'' AS GEOMETRY)'
SELECT @S = REPLACE(@S,'|','SELECT CAST(''POLYGON ((0 0,')
EXEC (@S)  --execute query
```

Original T_SQL:

```
DECLARE @C INT = 1,@S VARCHAR(MAX) = '',@G VARCHAR(99)='SELECT CAST(''POLYGON ((0 0, 1 0, 1 .1, 0 .1, 0 0))'' AS GEOMETRY) G UNION ALL ' 

WHILE @C<=31 --loop is just to cycle through the colors 

BEGIN
    SET @S+=@G  --MERGE SELECT STATEMENTS OF UNVIEWABLE OBJECTS (TOO SMALL) FOR WRONG COLORS 
    IF @C=14 SET @S+='SELECT CAST(''POLYGON ((0 0, 78 0, 78 26, 0 26, 0 0))'' AS GEOMETRY) UNION ALL '  --ADD TOP OF FLAG IN BLUE
    SET @C+=1   --UPDATE COLOR COUNTER
END

SET @S+='SELECT CAST(''POLYGON ((0 0, 78 0, 78 -26, 0 -26, 0 0))'' AS GEOMETRY)' --ADD BOTTOM OF FLAG IN YELLOW(ish)

EXEC (@S)  --execute query
```

Unfortunately, the colors look a little faded. Apologies to Ukraine for the bad colors. There don't seem to be too many colors available and they are all faded tones.

SQL Fiddle doesn't handle the spatial data. If there's another fiddle site that does, let me know or add a link. Or if there's a way to set the colors.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer! Had no idea SQL was capable of graphical output.

Comment: hello, nice answer. I see some places this can be golfed, I suspect this can be at least 100 characters shorter. Everything inside your WHILE can be written as 1 expression, this allows you to remove BEGIN and END. G does not need to be declared as a variable as you only use it once and the last SET and SELECT can be written in 1 expression. C<=31 can be written as C<32

Comment: I tried to golf your answer, I cut a few corners. Feel free to copy whatever you want from **[this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f58a6f72ad866960f328052e55eedb3d)**

Comment: @t-clausen.dk - thanks. I have included your changes and removed some line breaks and spaces.

Comment: you can still remove some of the spaces. You can use a line break instead of a otherwise necessary space, this will not change the length of the code

Answer (score 16):

## Python 3 + Pillow, <s>120</s> 100 bytes

```py
from PIL.Image import*;i=new("RGB",(78,52));i.putdata([(0,87,183)]*2028+[(255,215,0)]*2028);i.show()
```

Comment: You can shorten this a little bit by using `[(0,87,183)]*2028+[(255,215,0)]*2028` instead of the list comprehension.

Comment: Another note: using `;` instead of `\n` doesn't make a difference in bytes, so you can use newlines, unless of course you want to keep the decreased readability ;-).

Comment: @SylvesterKruin this is CGSE, of _course_ I want decreased readability /s

Answer (score 16):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>72</s> <s>58</s> 55 bytes

```r
barplot(rbind(1,1),3,co=c("gold","#0557b7"),bo=NA,as=1)
```

[Try it on rdrr.io!](https://rdrr.io/snippets/embed/?code=barplot(rbind(1%2C1)%2C3%2Cco%3Dc(%22gold%22%2C%22%230557b7%22)%2Cbo%3DNA%2Cas%3D1))

Comment: ```image(t(1:2),c=c("gold","#0557b7"),ax=F)```

Comment: @DominicvanEssen this was my first try, but it doesn't keep the ratio constant and depends on the viewing area.

Comment: Ah, yes.  With that in mind I like yours more!

Comment: I feel like there is a way to use the `bg` argument/parameter and just plot one colour letting the background take care of the rest, but struggling to actually execute --- anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 15):

## [QBasic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QBasic), 56 bytes

```
SCREEN 9
LINE(1,1)-(99,33),1,BF
LINE(1,34)-(99,66),14,BF
```

Try it at [Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/msdos_qbasic_megapack).

Draws a 99x66 flag on the screen:

[image: Ukrainian flag with "Press any key to continue" message]

Comment: Those colors don't look exact, but I'm assuming QBasic has a very limited color palette?

Comment: Yeah, there are only 16 colors to choose from. I actually think color 9, light blue, looks a bit closer than color 1, but the OP said "Use standard blue and yellow"... though I guess technically ANSI colors are only allowed if a solution uses character output (which I can't really do because QBasic's console is only 24 lines long)... so I guess if the OP says this is invalid, I can delete it.

Comment: Ah, I see you've already asked about it. "Closest available" works for me... except which is closer to `(0, 87, 183)`: `(0, 0, 170)` or `(0, 0, 255)`? Hmm...

Comment: I did do a bit of googling around and was actually able to find some [QBasic documentation](https://hwiegman.home.xs4all.nl/qb-man/index.html) someones hosting that says that with the screen mode you're using, it actually gets 64 colors on video adapters with >64k memory, although I couldn't find anything on what those colors actually *are*

Comment: Huh. I'm not sure how to access any colors beyond the basic set. Color values above 15 just turn out white when I try them in the `LINE` statement (on Archive.org, at least); in the `COLOR` statement, they give "Illegal function call." I do know that in screen mode 0, foreground colors 16-31 are the same as colors 0-15 except blinking...

Comment: I think I saw something on those docs about a `PALETTE USING` command that assigns different color palettes, but it wasn't entirely clear on how precisely it could assign colors. It's also possible that the Archive.org emulator is only simulating a 64k adapter, so the extra screen mode 9 colors aren't available at all.

Comment: Nice to see QBasic after all these years!  That was my first programming language!

Answer (score 13):

## HTML + CSS, 79 bytes

```html
<p style=background:#0057B7><p><style>*{aspect-ratio:3;margin:0;background:gold}
```

The final `}` should be removed, but this doesn't work in a Stack Snippet.

The HTML named colour `gold` is exactly the right colour for the yellow of the flag. I wonder whether this is a coincidence.

Answer (score 13):

## ZSH, 93 characters

This works in ZSH. I'm using Ubuntu, but ZSH on other systems should work fine. I have no hidden Unicode characters

```sh
a(){printf "`printf '.%.0s' {1..78}w`\n%.0s" {1..13}};printf '\033[44m';a;printf '\033[43m';a
```

### Output

[image: Screenshot of output]

Note: for some reason, if you run it many times, it breaks, so I advise running `reset` between invocations of this.

### Explanation

```sh
# make a function named a
a() {
  # generate a row of periods followed by a newline, and print that row 13 times. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5349842/16886597 for exactly what that does. Basically, this function creates a 78x13 grid of dots, and prints them to the screen
  printf "`printf '.%.0s' {1..78}w`\n%.0s" {1..13}
};
# set the color to blue
printf '\033[44m';
# print the dots
a;
# set the color to yellow
printf '\033[43m';
# print the dots
a
```

Note that I also use [the shortcut](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/25572/106950) for command substitution, saving one char.

Comment: You can replace `{1..13}` and `{1..78}` with `{a..m}` and `{+..y}` respectively, because there are still the correct number of characters in each of those ranges. You also don't need that `w`.

Answer (score 13):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) `-F`, 38 bytes

```
eval ';<<<␛[4'{4,3}m\${(l:78+{a..m}:)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjWbSSrptS7IKlpSVpuhY31VLLEnMU1K1tbGyko03Uq010jGtzY1SqNXKszC20qxP19HJrrTRrIaqhmhZAaQA)

`␛` should be the literal ASCII escape character, but this doesn't display in StackExchange markdown.

### Demo

[image: Screenshot of terminal showing the code being run and a Ukrainian flag being printed]

Answer (score 13):

## [Unicorn](https://www.theedkins.co.uk/jo/games/unicorn/unicorn.htm), <s>14</s> 10 bytes

```
P3X4Y3C7P3
```

[image: canvas with flag between (4,4) and (6,3)]

Note: There isn't a closer blue; the alternative is cyan.

Comment: Amazing! 14 bytes

Comment: @BlackMild As it turns out, that wasn't even a great way to do it. I got it down to 10

Answer (score 12):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), <s>56</s> 54 bytes

```
C=rgb([0,255],[87,215],[183,0])
[2,0]<y<[4,2]\{0<x<6\}
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eb0fptvvyq)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eymchoky7s)

I noticed that when I converted the rgb values to hsv, I got that both had a common s value of `100.0`. It saves one byte compared to rgb, but I wasn't sure if the values I got were exact or if they were just rounded (especially the v value of 71.8 for the blue color), so I decided not to use hsv in case it was inaccurate.

Comment: huh that HSV observation is interesting, but based on a quick conversion myself I'm getting `212,97,72` and `51,51,100` for the blue and yellow respectively, so I doubt there's a golfing opportunity there

Comment: @des54321 I used an online tool for the conversion because I don't know how to do it by hand, so it could be possible that the online tool is wrong. I got `211, 100, 71.8` for blue and `51, 100, 100` for yellow, using this [tool](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsv.html) I found online.

Comment: hmmm I plugged it into that tool too and I got `212,97.3,71.8` for the hsv, possibly you mis-typed something? I reversed it and the hsv you're getting seems to be hex `#0558b7`, instead of `#0557b7`

Comment: @des54321 I found the problem. The question body put `(0, 87, 183)` for the rgb value for blue (which was what I was using for the conversion) which is apparently different from the hex value that follows immediately afterwards (`#0557B7`), which has a rgb value of `(5, 87, 183)`.  Now I'm not sure which one I'm supposed to be using because different answers use different values 0_0

Comment: Oh hold on LMAO, in that case your number is right and the hex on the post is wrong, I was the one who edited the hexes into the original post, and it seems I made a small mistake on that one, the actual hex code should be '#0057b7`

Comment: @des54321 No need to suggest another edit, I'll just edit it directly (because I have over 2k rep)

Comment: TIL desmos supports RGB colors... 1+

Comment: What's the difference between the prettified version and the normal version? I don't see any

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing By prettified, I meant that the formatting of the code is prettified, not the actual graph. If you look in the golfed version of the graph, you can see that one of the equations doesn't render properly, but does in the prettified graph.

Comment: @mathcat You can learn more about Desmos custom colors [here](https://help.desmos.com/hc/en-us/articles/4406795899533-Custom-Colors).

Answer (score 12):

### Asymptote <s>88</s> 82 bytes

(I update my shortest code here, including its history. Hope that it is legal!)

Run on http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/

```
// Asymptote 82 bytes
fill(box((0,0),(78,26)),rgb(0,87,183));fill(box((0,0),(78,-26)),rgb("#FFD700"));
```

---

```
// Asymptote 88 bytes
fill(box((0,0),(300,100)),rgb(0,87,183));
fill(box((0,0),(300,-100)),rgb(255,215,0));
```

[image]

---

In this world of civilization, it's hard to believe that there have been an invasion war from Russia. Stand with Ukraine!

[image]

[image]

Appendix
**TikZ 125 bytes** (by @Joe85AC)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}\begin{document}\tikz{\def~#1;{\color[HTML]{#1}\fill rectangle(3,}~0057b7;);~ffd700;-1)}\stop
```

**TikZ 187 bytes**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}\begin{document}\tikz{\definecolor{b}{RGB}{0,87,183}\definecolor{r}{RGB}{255,215,0}\fill[b](0,0)rectangle(3,1);\fill[r](0,0)rectangle(3,-1);}\end{document}
```

**TikZ 297 bytes**

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\definecolor{Ukraine blue}{RGB}{0,87,183}
\definecolor{Ukraine yellow}{RGB}{255,215,0}
\fill[Ukraine blue] (0,0) rectangle (3,1);
\fill[Ukraine yellow] (0,0) rectangle (3,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Presumably you could shave bytes by renaming "Ukraine blue" just "b" etc?

Comment: @SteveBennett Thanks! I have added an update. In LaTeX, `b` is allowed, but `y` is not (also `x`). So I use `ux` instead.

Comment: The second picture (Nature) has zero code, thus it must be the winner.
I REALY LIKE IT

Comment: TikZ: 158 bytes -->
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}\def~{document}\begin~\tikz{\definecolorset{HTML}{}{}{b,0057b7;g,ffd700}\def~{rectangle(4,}\fill(,)[b]~2);\fill(,)[g]~0)}
\end~

Comment: @Joe85AC Fantastic! Could you explain about `(,)` ? I see that it is not `(0,0)`

Comment: @BlackMild tikz uses 1 as default value in coordinates if you leave it blank... I just tried to optimize it a little further. I guess, there was still some room for improvement but i was tired yesterday evening (German time)... TikZ, 152 bytes: \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}\def~{document}\begin~\tikz{\definecolorset{HTML}{}{}{b,0057b7;g,ffd700}\def~#1{\fill(,)[#1]rectangle(4,}~b2);~g0)}\end~

Comment: Optimized it a little further: 125 bytes --> \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}\begin{document}\tikz{\def~#1;{\color[HTML]{#1}\fill rectangle(3,}~0057b7;);~ffd700;-1)}\stop

Comment: @Joe85AC Nice! I have just update your code to the post

Answer (score 11):

## HTML4, <s>98</s> <s>95</s> 85 bytes

```html
<table width=78 height=52 cellspacing=0><tr><td bgcolor=#0057B7><tr><td bgcolor=gold>
```

Edit: Saved 3 bytes by using @pxeger's observation that `gold` is `#FFD700`. Saved 10 bytes thanks to @IsmaelMiguel. Note that the sizes here work in Firefox but other browsers may have other default table styles which alter the resulting size.

Comment: HTML is not a programming language /s

Comment: Why use a table? Simple CSS will save at least 50 bytes...

Comment: @code Because this isn't an HTML+CSS answer...

Comment: `<table width=80 height=56 cellspacing=0><tr><td bgcolor=#0057B7><tr><td bgcolor=gold>` <-- Save 10 bytes. It works on Google Chrome 99.0.4844.74 on Windows 10. This makes an 80x56px table with spacing around, with each row taking 78x26px each.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Huh, Firefox developer tools tells me that I need `width=78 height=52` so I'll stick with those values but thanks for the 10 byte saving!

Comment: @Neil You're welcome. Don't forget to specify that this was tested on Firefox and has the correct sizes on it. On Google Chrome, 78 pixels wide makes a 76px wide flag, and the 52px height makes a 48px tall flag with 24px tall segments.

Answer (score 11):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <s>107</s> <s>106</s> <s>92</s> <s>86</s> 85 bytes

*NOTE: you can't actually copy the escape characters from the code below for some reason. Be sure to click the try it online link if you want to test the code; ***don't copy it from the answer!*** The odd thing is, the escape characters could be copied in the *edit preview*, but not in the actual *answer*. I've asked a [question on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377341/1156839) about it.*

```rust
fn main(){print!("[38;2;0;87;183m{}[38;5;220m{0}",("X".repeat(78)+"
").repeat(13))}
```

If you want one more byte, you can use `█` instead of `X`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvn/Py1PITcxM09Ds7qgKDOvRFFDSTra2MLayNrA2sLc2tDCOLe6Fixiam1kZJBbbVCrpKOhFKGkV5RakJpYomFuoamtxKWkCeMbGmtq1v7/DwA)

**To 106 bytes:** Removed the first `r,` and added a `0` in the second pair of braces `{}`.

**To 92 bytes:** Thanks to [Toothbrush's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/15022/toothbrush) help, I was able to reduce the code even more by removing the `let` statement, rearranging the formatting, and changing the gold color to  220.

**To 86 bytes:** Credit to [Aiden4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/97691/aiden4), I reduced the code to 86 bytes by using literal escape characters. I know you can't see them in the code, but you *can* see them [online (86-byte version)](https://tio.run/##KyotLvn/Py1PITcxM09Ds7qgKDOvRFFDSTra2MLayNrA2sLc2tDCOLe6Fixiam1kZJBbbVCrpKOhFKGkV5RakJpYomFuoamtFJOnpAkTMDTW1Kz9/x8A).

**To 85 bytes:** Removed the `\n` and just used an actual newline in the code.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer! You can also use https://tio.run/#rust to check the byte count of an answer.

Comment: You don't need the `let` statement: `fn main(){print!("\x1b[38;2;0;87;183m{}\x1b[38;2;255;215;0m{0}",("X".repeat(78)+"\n").repeat(13))}` is 98 bytes.
Also, you can save 1 byte by deduplicating part of the format string: `fn main(){print!("{}0;87;183m{1}{0}255;215;0m{1}","\x1b[38;2;",("X".repeat(78)+"\n").repeat(13))}` is 97 bytes

Comment: Also, if you use standard blue and yellow as allowed in the rules, you can use `fn main(){print!("\x1b[34m{}\x1b[33m{0}",("X".repeat(78)+"\n").repeat(13))}` (75 bytes).

Comment: If not, you can use `fn main(){print!("\x1b[38;2;0;87;183m{}\x1b[38;5;220m{0}",("X".repeat(78)+"\n").repeat(13))}` (92 bytes) since colour 220 is exactly `#ffd700`.

Comment: @Toothbrush Thanks for the tips! I'll use your last suggestion, since the rules say _Colors must be exact_ **if possible**. The `let` statement was left over from when I was at 107 bytes, and I didn't think to remove it.

Comment: You can use a literal escape character instead of using an ASCII escape for the escape character to get down to 86 bytes. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvn/Py1PITcxM09Ds7qgKDOvRFFDSTra2MLayNrA2sLc2tDCOLe6Fixiam1kZJBbbVCrpKOhFKGkV5RakJpYomFuoamtFJOnpAkTMDTW1Kz9/x8A)

Answer (score 10):

## Python 3 + `pygame`, <strike>124</strike> 117 bytes

There's already two other python solutions to this problem, but I might as well add a third.

```python
from pygame import*
d,r=display,draw.rect
s=d.set_mode()
r(s,"#0557b7",(0,0,78,26))
r(s,"gold",(0,26,78,26))
d.flip()
```

There might be something I could golf by being smarter with sizes, but this seems pretty close to optimal. By pure luck, `"gold"` happens to be exactly equal to `#ffd700` in pygame's color library, scraping off 3 bytes.

Edit -7 bytes: Hold on a sec apparently you don't actually need to do `pygame.init()`??? I strongly suspect this is undefined behavior, but it works even running from the command line, so who am I to argue.

Output:

[image: A mostly black screen with a small Ukrainian flag displaying in the top left corner]

Comment: For removing `pygame.init()`, I remember reading somewhere that it just imports all pygame modules, so that you don't need to manually import any of them yourself. It is highly recommended, but not required.

Comment: @AidenChow ah that makes sense, luckily this is PPCG, where all recommendations of good coding fall in the face of shorter code :P

Answer (score 9):

## WebP, 42 bytes

```
UklGRiIAAABXRUJQVlA4TBUAAAAvTcAMABCQJEPb3TRh/me3/5nUH/UA
```

Encoded in Base64 RFC4648

Comment: 36 bytes - UklGRhwAAABXRUJQVlA4TA8AAAAvAkAAAPhW9fzPbv+D5DYA (3x2 image, breaks rules)

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript/HTML <s>117</s> <s>112</s> <s>102</s> <s>100</s> 98 bytes

```js
c=c.getContext`2d`
f=k=>c.fillRect(0,(c.fillStyle=k)>c?33:0,99,33)
f`gold`,f`#0057b7`
```

```html
<canvas id=c>
```

With continued help from @Samathingamajig and @pxeger's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/245327/53067)

1. `<canvas id=c>` is invalid HTML when missing an end tag but at least Chromium-Edge and Firefox create the element anyway.
2. `` c=c.getContext`2d` ``  is using [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates) syntax,

---

Slava Ukraini!

Comment: You can remove 2 bytes with `<canvas id=c>`

Comment: Another 2 bytes removed with `c=c.getContext\`2d\``

Comment: Yet another 2 bytes removed with `c.fillRect(0,y,78,26)`

Comment: You're never gonna believe this, but there are another 2 bytes that can be removed with `f=(k,y=0)` and `f\`#0057b7\`` (now at 104 bytes)

Comment: @Samathingamajig  Super helpful and thanks  - I'd not used template literals before. The only reason I didn't use your last and impressively sneaky suggestion was I dropped the `y` parameter to shave 4 instead of 2 bytes off (now at 102 bytes)

Comment: Again another 2 bytes removed with `f=k=>c.fillRect(0,(c.fillStyle=k)>'$'?33:0,99,33)`

Comment: Is the thing you got from @pxeger the `gold` keyword or something else?

Comment: @Samathingamajig yes it was the use of `gold` -  here used as part of the golphing, not just to shorten the string itself. And your last improvement was impressive, thank you again!

Comment: Hoping to get it to be below 100 chars, but all my changes are either staying the same or increasing.

Comment: Once again, I have removed 2 bytes from the solution. `(c.fillStyle=k)>c?33:0` .... This works because `(x.fillStyle=k)` is a string, so a comparison operator (except for `===` and `!==`, and maybe some others) will try to convert the context to a string, which is `"[object CanvasRenderingContext2D]"`. ASCII `[` is 91, `#` is 35, and `g` is 103. So 35 is not > 91, and 103 is > 91. It's the same amount of characters to wrap in parentheses and do multiplication by 33 :(

Comment: @Samathingamajig I'm in awe. If I get a "move to chat" I'll delete some of my responses. Working on a Node/JavaScript 89 byte alternative, but need some golfing time before posting...

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to break the tradition of recommending changes that reduce the byte count by 2 to suggest one that only reduces it by 1: `(c.fillStyle=k)>c&&33`

Answer (score 9):

## Java, 169 bytes

```java
import java.awt.*;v->new Frame(){public void paint(Graphics g){for(int i=0;i<2;g.fillRect(0,i*30-i/2*4,78,26))g.setColor(new Color(i*255,i*128+87,++i%2*183));}{show();}}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Explanation:**

```java
import java.awt.*;        // Required import for Frame/Graphics/Color
v->                       // Method with empty unused parameter and Frame return
  new Frame(){            //  Create a Frame (window for graphical output)
    public void paint(Graphics g){
                          //   Overwrite its default paint method:
      for(int i=0;i<2     //    Loop `i` in the range [0,2):
          ;               //      After every iteration:
           g.fillRect(    //       Draw the rectangle
             0,i*30-i/2*4,//       at x,y position 0,30i-i//2*4 (i=1→30; i=2→56),
                          //       where the +30 is to account for the title-bar
             78,26))      //       of 78 pixels wide and 26 pixels high
                          //       (so the flag is the minimum required 78x52)
       g.setColor(new Color(i*255,i*128+87,++i%2*183));}
                          //     Change the RGB-color based on `i`:
                          //      i=0 (blue):     0, 87,183
                          //      i=1 (yellow): 255,215,  0
                          //     (and increase `i` by 1 with `++i`)
  {                       //   And in an inner initializer block:
   show();}}              //    Show the frame
```

Comment: Impressive! java golfing always gets a +1 from me

Answer (score 9):

## Perl (51 characters)

The following piece of code writes the file as a PNM picture

```
say"P6 78 52 255 ","\0W\xb7"x2028,"\xff\xd7\0"x2028
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I just came up with too! You can save a few bytes using the raw chars directly though: https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#eyJsYW5nIjoid2VicGVybC01LjI4LjEiLCJjb2RlIjoiMDAwMDAwMDA6IDczNjEgNzkyNyA1MDM2IDBhMzcgMzgwYSAzNTMyIDBhMzIgMzUzNSAgc2F5J1A2Ljc4LjUyLjI1NVxuMDAwMDAwMTA6IDBhMjcgMmMyNyAwMDU3IGI3MjcgNzgzMiAzMDMyIDM4MmMgMjdmZiAgLicsJy5XLid4MjAyOCwnLlxuMDAwMDAwMjA6IGQ3MDAgMjc3OCAzMjMwIDMyMzggICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgLi4neDIwMjgiLCJhcmdzIjoiLU01LjEwLjAiLCJtaW1lIjoiaW1hZ2UveC1wb3J0YWJsZS1iaXRtYXAifQ==

Answer (score 9):

## [D Language](https://dlang.org/), 122 bytes

### Code

```d
import std.stdio;
void main(){
char[78]l='.';
foreach(c;["\033[44m","\033[43m"])foreach(x;0..13)writeln(c,l,"\033[0m");
}
```

### Output

[image: program execution results]

Comment: Welcome to CGCC!

Answer (score 9):

## [`dc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dc_(computer_program)), <del>73</del> <del>71</del> 68 bytes

```
0d34[27P91PnA9P]dsax[33lax]sc[APd-r1+r]sn[35Pr1+d77<nrdD=cd26>u]dsux
```

#### Output:

[image: Output]

Outputs a 78x26 grid of coloured '#' characters to stdout. This is a 3:2 aspect ratio assuming that the font's aspect ratio is 1:2.

#### Edits:

-2 bytes: use integers rather than strings for the newline and # character

-3 bytes: it turns out that dc will treat 'A' as 10 and 'D' as 13, even with the input radix set to 10. It also treats 'A9' as 109 (i.e. 'm') for some reason (looks like it treats each digit separately?)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 8):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 94 bytes

```lisp
(require 2htdp/image)(define(f c)(rectangle 78 26"solid"c))(above(f(color 0 87 183))(f"gold"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

### Batch, 93 bytes

```
@for %%i in (44 103)do @for /l %%j in (1,1,12)do @set/p=␛[%%im%PATH:~,80%<nul
@set/p=␛[m<nul
```

Assumes a default 80×25 screen with a `PATH` variable of at least 80 characters (this is true on a default Windows 10 installation). The last line is to stop the prompt appearing in yellow which wouldn't be a line of at least 78 non-whitespace characters and would therefore be illegal.

Note that `␛` is used to represent the nonprintable `` (good luck copying and pasting that).

Answer (score 8):

## Python 3 + `tkinter`, <s>132</s> <s>128</s> 124 bytes

There are several Python 3 answers already here, but none of them use `tkinter`, so I thought I'd add one that uses `tkinter.Canvas`:

```python
from tkinter import*
c=Canvas(Tk())
c.pack()
d=c.create_rectangle
d(5,5,83,31,f="#0057B7")
d(5,31,83,57,f="gold")
mainloop()
```

**To 128 bytes:** Thanks to the help of [pxeger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/97857/pxeger), using a wildcard import reduces the size by 4 bytes.

**To 124 bytes:** Thanks to the help of [des54321](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/111305/des54321), removing the space before the `*` and changing the `#FFD700` to `gold` reduced the code by another 4 bytes.

Outputs a mostly empty screen with the flag in the corner:

[image]

Comment: It's a bit shorter to use a wildcard import: `from tkinter import*;c=Canvas(Tk());c.pack();d=c.create_rectangle;d(5,5,83,31,f="#0057B7");d(5,31,83,57,f="#FFD700");mainloop()`

Comment: @pxeger Done. Thanks!

Comment: The space before the asterisk isnt necessary, `from tkinter import*` instead of `import *` works and saves a byte, and if tkinter recognizes standard HTML color names you can replace `"#FFD700" with "gold", as it happens to be the exact same color, saving another 3 bytes

Comment: @des54321 Done. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>126</s> <s>115</s> 109 bytes

- -6 thanks to ceilingcat
- -6 thanks to AZTECCO
- -3 by using `gold` which seems to work instead of `#FFD700`

Produces an XPM image. If there's another indexed colour format that is smaller to produce from C, I'd be very interested!

```c
i;a(c){for(i=2730;i--;putchar(i%91?c:10));}f(){puts("! XPM2\n90 60 2 1\na c #0057B7\nb c gold");a(97);a(98);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcwxC8IwFATgvb/iWRHyhkAS0RiDCO6Co0OW@ErbgCai1SX0t8fgcnB38BEfiEoJ1jPC3KcXCwel18IGzu3zM9Ho67Qy8kh7KRDt3DPM9XizdgHXy1m5aARsBSiQLnogWAqx0Sft4q2WId27Fqtu9D93VSghTvDwIbJvCh1CbgCqapu5/AA)

Comment: Nice one! [Some savings](https://tio.run/##HcwxC8IwEAXgvb/irAjJEEgLNcYggrvg6JAlXml7oIlodQn97fFwefDegw/ViFgKuSBQ5iG9BB1aY7UjpdzzM@MUeNpYfcR9o6V0yyBk5uMt6hVcL@fWR6thq6GFxscACGvddeZkfLxxGdO9ryXr1vxzx0KhOMMjUBTfRL2EXAGw6qql/AA "C (gcc) – Try It Online") by using only putchar, please check if I didn't broken the dimensions

Comment: [108 bytes](https://tio.run/##FY2xCsIwFEX3fsWzIrwMgSSiMQYR3AVHhyzxlbYBTUSrS@i3xzjee7jnEh@ISgnWI7HcpxeGg9JrYQPn9vmZaPS1Whl5NDtOeykYs3OPLFf2xnYB18tZuWgEbAUokC56IFgKsdEn7eKthiHdu5bVA4/yvy4hTvDwIeI3hY5BbgCq0TZz@QE)

Answer (score 8):

### JavaScript (browser console), 94 bytes

```js
j='height:4em;width:12em;display:block;background:',console.log('%c %c ',j+`#0057B7`,j+`gold`)
```

### 96 bytes

```js
console.log('%c %c ',`${j='height:4em;width:12em;display:block;background:'}#0057B7`,`${j}gold`)
```

This is shorter (85 bytes), but in a bit of a grey area? If you size the console perfectly, the output will be the correct dimensions:

```javascript
console.log('%c %c ',`${j='display:block;height:6em;background:'}#0057B7`,`${j}gold`)
```

### 97 characters

```js
console.log('%c %c ',`${j='height:26px;width:78px;display:block;background:'}#0057B7`,`${j}gold`)
```

I think this works in most browsers these days?

[image]

(Incidentally, I note that the image in the question is not actually the colours described.)

Answer (score 8):

## [C (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org), 78 bytes

```
main(i){puts("P6\n78 52\n255");for(;i<4057;)printf(i++<2029?"%cW\xb7":"\xff\xd7%c",0);}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700OT49OXnBgqWlJWm6FjczksLdCpIyMwq8I0rKUyKCqrydvQL9cipK_arS0_1CvJKTsjwN_YI9C_yNosqSM9PNE0PKDXxdQo39K3PKk3NzSlPcI_MTg4uLAlw8y32zsvU9M8OywsyTM_0zffQNK8OyPDPLy71DSiyXJSUWp5qZQO2F2Q8A) (code in Base64)

Outputs a [PPM](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html) image to STDOUT.

Comment: Good answer! For those wondering how to save the image, they can run the compiled binary and redirect the output to a file. For example: `/home/user/compiledflag > /home/user.flag.ppm`.

Comment: And for those wondering how to view the image, PPM is a format supported by most *NIX image tools, such as GIMP or the default GNOME Image Viewer (and many other, these are the ones installed on my system). 
:)

Comment: [-7 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPI1OzOi2/SKOgtKRYQynALCbP3ELB1Cgmz8jUVEnTOtPGxMDU3FqzvCizJFXDUCdTW9vGyMDI0l4pxiA8piLJXMnKR@nt/P1KOsaa1rX//wMA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 8):

## HTML, 73 bytes

```html
<p style=aspect-ratio:3/2;background:linear-gradient(#0057B7+50%,gold+50%
```

Thanks to @pxeger for pointing out that you can remove the quotes and not close the tag.

Comment: -3 bytes with the usual HTML abuse: `<p style=aspect-ratio:3/2;background:linear-gradient(#0057B7+50%,gold+50%`

Answer (score 7):

## [Coding](https://bennyboy.tech/codinglang/), 84 bytes

```
>p
(width:78px;border-top:26px solid #FFD700;border-bottom:26px solid #0057B7)@style
```

borrowing from the CSS answer.

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/245318/draw-the-ukrainian-flag/245319?noredirect=1#comment550682_245320 <-- check this comment to save a few bytes.

Answer (score 7):

## PostScript, 191 bytes

Prints the flag starting at 1"x1"; 3"x2" in size. This is my first try at a PostScript submission, so it's probably not the smallest possible.

```
%!
/i{72 mul}def/c{255 div}def/b{newpath moveto 3 i 0 i rlineto 0 i 1 i rlineto -3 i 0 i rlineto closepath fill}def 0 87 c 183 c setrgbcolor 0 i 1 i b 1 215 c 0 setrgbcolor 0 i 0 i b showpage
```

Answer (score 7):

## Bash (+ Image Magick) <strike>69</strike> <strike>67</strike> 64 characters

The following command will output the required file on standard output (as a PNM picture) if Image Magick is installed. Since I had some issues with binary value 0 in both RGB color codes, I replaced it with 1 instead:

```
convert - -scale 78x52\! -<<<$'P6 1 2 255 \x01W\xb7\xff\xd7\x01'
```

Comment: See [Digital Trauma](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11259/digital-trauma)'s [tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41182) on using here-string to reduce the length.

Comment: @manatwork Thank you, done!

Answer (score 7):

## [PaperScript](http://paperjs.org/about/), 80 bytes

```
R=Path.Rectangle
R(1,1,99,33).fillColor="#0057b7"
R(1,34,99,33).fillColor="gold"
```

[Try it here!](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.15/S/q1bKS8xNVbJSCs5OLUnOUNJRSs5PAfGDbAMSSzL0glKTSxLz0nNSY4pi8oI0DHUMdSwtdYyNNfXSMnNynPNz8otsY5SUDQxMzZPMY5RgqoxNsClLz89JiVEC2pFUlJqYXZCfmVdSrGQVHVsLAA==)

Answer (score 7):

**Commodore 64 machine code, <s>36 33</s> 31 bytes**

Code

```
.C:c000  78          SEI
.C:c001  A9 80       LDA #$80
.C:c003  A0 97       LDY #$97
.C:c005  8D 11 D0    STA $D011
.C:c008  2C 11 D0    BIT $D011
.C:c00b  F0 FB       BEQ $C008
.C:c00d  2C 11 D0    BIT $D011
.C:c010  D0 FB       BNE $C00D
.C:c012  8C 20 D0    STY $D020
.C:c015  CC 12 D0    CPY $D012
.C:c018  D0 FB       BNE $C015
.C:c01a  CE 20 D0    DEC $D020
.C:c01d  D0 E9       BNE $C008
.c01f  
(C:$c01f) g c000
```

Output

[image: Output]

Edit 1: Found a way to reuse the stx$d020 without introducing flickering. Geometry change: +1 raster scan line of blue, -1 of yellow. Tweaked saturation and brightness settings on the virtual CRT to obtain nicer colors.

Edit 2: Got rid of one register and saved two bytes.

Edit 3: Edit 2 reintroduced the overscan flicker, argh! This is fixed now. Geometry change: another extra line of blue at the expense of a line of yellow. Ditched the virtual CRT tweak, this is the output with the external palette called "VICE".

Comment: colors look a bit bleached compared to the specification, but I assume that this is the closest a commodore 64 can do?

Comment: I really hope you have a working commodore 64 to run this on.

Comment: Yep. The emulator can use custom palettes tho.

Comment: I don't have a working c64, sorry :/

Comment: fair enough, given how old it is theres a good chance a c64 doesnt even have a well-specified color pallete

Comment: Analogue color output to TV, so no standard. Results would depend on your TV too.

Answer (score 7):

## [Processing](https://processing.org/), 92 Bytes

```
void setup(){size(78,52);background(#0057B7);}void draw(){fill(#FFD700);rect(0,26,78,26);}
```

**Output**

[image: Ukranian Flag]

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 7):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/) + [pixie](https://github.com/treeform/pixie), 139 bytes

```
import pixie
let
 i=78.newImage 52
 c=i.newContext
i.fill rgb(0,87,183)
c.fillStyle=rgb(255,215,0)
c.fillRect 0,26,78,26
i.writeFile"c.png"
```

Outputs to the file `c.png`.

[image]

Comment: You can replace `newImage(78,52)` with `78.newImage 52`.

Answer (score 6):

### Windows PowerShell / PowerShell Core, 50 bytes

Only works in a PowerShell host.

```
,'blue'*9+,'yellow'*9|%{Write-Host('█'*78)-f $_}
```

Output (bit outdated because code was edited):

[image: output]

I also reposted this code in [my GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/Tyler887/367072e384345b917a6d7a65920965b4).

Try it online not available, because it cannot render colors (so none of the flag is shown for tio.run).

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer.

Comment: 50 bytes with non-whitespace characters. `,'blue'*9+,'yellow'*9|%{Write-Host('█'*78)-f $_}`. Only works in a PowerShell host.

Answer (score 6):

## PostScript, <s>55</s> 43 bytes

```
00000000: 3188 0238 5b2e 3030 3288 0030 202d 2e30  1..8[.002..0 -.0
00000010: 3036 8800 325d 2800 57b7 ffd7 2992 a333  06..2](.W...)..3
00000020: 2063 6f6c 6f72 696d 6167 65               colorimage
```

Tokenized version of:

```
1 2 8[.002 0 0 -.006 0 2]<0057b7ffd7>stopped 3 colorimage
```

The original solution without binary tokens was a bit shorter at 55 bytes:

```
1 2 8[.002 0 0 -.006 0 2]<0057b7ffd7>false 3 colorimage
```

These all use a stretched a 1x2 bitmap. To view, run through Ghostscript.
[image: output]

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861), and nice first answer!

Answer (score 6):

## C# (.NET), 178 chars

### Effective code

```
var f=new Bitmap(78,52);for(int y=0;y<52;y++)for(int x=0;x<78;x++)if(y>25)f.SetPixel(x,y,Color.FromArgb(255,215,0));else f.SetPixel(x,y,Color.FromArgb(0,87,183));f.Save("f.bmp");
```

### Readable version

```
using System.Drawing;
namespace UkrainianFlag
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //The effective code could replace the code in this method.

            var blue = Color.FromArgb(0, 87, 183);
            var yellow = Color.FromArgb(255, 215, 0);

            //Create the image holding the flag.
            var flag = new Bitmap(78, 52);

            //Iterate the pixels, row by row.
            for (int y = 0; y < flag.Height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < flag.Width; x++)
                {
                    if (y >= flag.Height / 2)
                    {
                        flag.SetPixel(x, y, blue);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        flag.SetPixel(x, y, yellow);
                    }
                }
            }

            //Store the flag image next to the exe-file.
            flag.Save("flag.bmp");
        }
    }
}
```

### Output

[image: Example file of program output.]

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: `var f=new Bitmap(78,52);for(int i=0;i<4056;i++)f.SetPixel(i%78,i/78,i>1950?Color.FromArgb(255,215,0):Color.FromArgb(0,87,183));f.Save("f.bmp");`

Answer (score 5):

## MSWLogo, I'm assuming <s>173</s> 167 bytes.

```
to f :a :b :c :y
setpos(list 0 :y)
setpc(list :a :b :c)
repeat 2[fd 26 rt 90 fd 72 rt 90]
setpos(list 1 :y+1)
setfc(list :a :b :c)
fill
end
f 225 215 0 0 f 0 87 153 26
```

[image]

Comment: MSWLego? Didn't know they were doing code golf

Comment: @Ginger lol. saw a Scratch answer and I just thought to myself: "Let's do this in Logo"

Answer (score 5):

## [C++, GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) <strike>227</strike>216 chars

Hardly golf considering the language/tools, but still worth a try

```
#import<boost/gil/extension/io/pnm.hpp>
int n;int main(){boost::gil::rgb8_image_t i{999,666};for_each_pixel(view(i),[](auto&p){n++/999<333?p={0,87,183}:p={255,215,0};});write_view("U",view(i),boost::gil::pnm_tag{});}
```

It's not even obfuscated if reformatted:

```
#import <boost/gil/extension/io/pnm.hpp>
int n;
int main() {
    boost::gil::rgb8_image_t i{999, 666};
    for_each_pixel(view(i), [](auto& p) {
        n++ / 999 < 333 ? p = {0, 87, 183} : p = {255, 215, 0};
    });
    write_view("U", view(i), boost::gil::pnm_tag{});
}
```

The U file is in PNM format, meaning no link dependencies. Built with GCC-10 results in 19K binary.

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/PEdb8cfKb)**

Resulting file:

```
U: Netpbm image data, size = 999 x 666, rawbits, pixmap
```

[image]

Comment: [216 bytes](https://godbolt.org/z/T1qGW6a3s)

Comment: @gastropner Hah. Who'dve-thunk that you can simply `#import` header files :) Also, nice with the ternary around the assignment expression.

Answer (score 5):

## [SimpleTemplate](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/SimpleTemplate) 0.84, 102 bytes

This answer outputs a flag with 78x52 characters.

```
{@fori to51}{@forto77}<b{@ifi is lowerthan26} x{@/}>@{@/}<br>{@/}<style>b{color:#0057B7}[x]{color:gold
```

This code generates 20474 bytes of pure HTML nightmare, but works!

---

### Ungolfed

The golfed code is pretty hard to read, so, here's an ungolfed version.

```
{@for i from 0 to 51}
    {@for j from 0 to 77}
        {@echo "<b"}
        {@if i is lower than 26}
            {@echo " x"}
        {@/}
        {@echo ">@"}
    {@/}
    {@echo "<br>"}
{@/}
{@echo "<style>b{color:#0057B7}[x]{color:gold"}
```

This code behaves exactly the same as the golfed version.

---

### Output

This is a nightmare, but, it outputs the following (lightly edited to work as a StackSnippet):

```css
b{color:#0057B7}[x]{color:gold
```

```html
<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<br><b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<br><b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<br><b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<br><b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<br><b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<br><b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<br><b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<br><b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<br><b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<br><b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<br><b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<br><b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<br><b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<br><b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<br><b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<br><b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<br><b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<br><b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<br><b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<br><b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<br><b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<br><b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<br><b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<br><b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<br><b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<b x>@<br><b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<br><b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<br><b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<br><b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<br><b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<br><b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<br><b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<br><b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<br><b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<br><b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<br><b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<br><b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<br><b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<br><b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<br><b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<br><b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<br><b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<br><b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<br><b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<br><b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<br><b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<br><b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<br><b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<br><b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<br><b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<br><b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<b>@<br>
```

---

---

You can try the code here: https://www.ideone.com/xIjh40

Answer (score 5):

## Python 3, <s>330</s> 273 bytes

The following piece of code shows the Ukrainian flag in coloured text when executed in the Windows Command Prompt

```
import sys
from termcolor import *
import os
os.system("")
t=colored("#","blue",attrs=["reverse","blink"])
for x in range(26):
    for x in range(78):
        print(end=t)
    print()
t=colored("#","yellow",attrs=["reverse","blink"])
for x in range(26):
    for x in range(78):
        print(end=t)
    print()
```

Try It Online is not available, for the reason it wouldn't display the colours.

Comment: Can golf this down to [273 bytes](https://tio.run/##tY07DsIwEER7n2K1NEkUUYAECCkniSiAbISF7Y3Wy8enNyGEippy3jzNDEkvHNY5Wz@wKMQUTS/sQUn8mR0LfJrKzAZHw3E5ekq@QCyNNpNHXYELrPHkboT1UVVi06LQnSTSxG244qE0/bj5BBsAAavVZm/gTdKXbHcjgUFs0IJC12hp5vRzlcg5fvzpLOcX) by trimming indent whitespace, using an `import*`, `print(end=t)` instead of `print(t,end="")`, and some smarter iterators because you arent using the value x in the for loops

Comment: When running on linux you can safely remove the `os.system("")` line

Answer (score 5):

## Dyalog APL,55 byte

```
(⊂'P3 78 52 255 ',⍕,⍉2028/(3⍴256)⊤22455 16766720)∘⎕NPUT
```

Write a plain text [PPM](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ppm) image to provided filename.

[image: Sample]

```
$ cat out.ppm
P3 78 52 255 0 87 183 0 87 183 0 87 183 0 87 183 0 87 183 0 87 183 0 87
183 0 87 183 0 87 183 0 87 183 0 87 183 0 87 183 0 87 183 0 87 183 0 87
...
183 0 87 183 0 87 183 0 87 183 0 87 183 0 87 183 0 87 183 0 87 183 0 87
183 0 87 183 255 215 0 255 215 0 255 215 0 255 215 0 255 215 0 255 215 0
255 215 0 255 215 0 255 215 0 255 215 0 255 215 0 255 215 0 255 215 0
255 215 0 255 215 0 255 215 0 255 215 0 255 215 0 255 215 0 255 215 0
...
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Applesoft Basic](https://inexorabletash.github.io/jsbasic/reference.html), 88 bytes

```
1Y=0
2M=13
3GR
4COLOR=2
5HLIN0,38ATY
6Y=Y+1
7IFY<M GOTO5
8COLOR=13
9M=26
10Y=13
11GOTO5
```

Kind of cheating because it only is 39:26. I don't know if this is actually valid but it works [here](https://inexorabletash.github.io/jsbasic/). A high res but worse color answer for 93 bytes:

```
1Y=0
2M=26
3HGR
4HCOLOR=6
5HPLOT0,Y TO78,Y
6Y=Y+1
7IFY<M GOTO5
8HCOLOR=5
9M=52
10Y=26
11GOTO5
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 36 bytes

```perl
$#a=78;print".[${_}m@a
"x13for 44,43
```

[Try it online!](https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#eyJsYW5nIjoid2VicGVybC01LjI4LjEiLCJjb2RlIjoiJCNhPTc4O3ByaW50XCJcdTAwMWJbJHtffW1AYVxuXCJ4MTNmb3IgNDQsNDMifQ==)

Outputs using ANSI escape sequences.

Comment: For some reason, the link seems to show an 'L'-shaped flag with a long extension at the bottom right.  Is this just a side-effect of the 'code sandbox'?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Yeah, it's a side effect of ANSI escape codes being used in a window that's not long enough for the content, the same happens in a local terminal if you're most of the way down. It's annoying. I did briefly look at auto-sizing STDOUT for code-sandbox, but it would need to be resized before the content makes it there...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Thanks for the nudge, I've just made a fix so that the xterm window will resize on input (not sure how quickly the cache is invalidated on GitHub pages, but thanks again for the prompt!)

Comment: Works perfectly now.  Nice one.

Answer (score 5):

SVG, 132 bytes

```html
<svg width="300"height="200"><rect width="300"height="100"fill="#0057b7"/><rect y="100"width="300"height="100"fill="#ffd700"/></svg>
```

Answer (score 5):

## WP2, 32 bytes

```
VWtsR1JpSUFBQUJYUlVKUVZsQTRUQlVBQUFBdlRjQU1BQkNRSkVQYjNUUmgvbWUzLzVuVUgvVUEK
```

WP2 (WebP2) is an image format based on AVIF. It's state-of-the-art in the field of DCT-based image formats, as far as I'm aware. It's also really good at lossless compression.

Encoded in Base64 RFC4648

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby + paint, 73 bytes

You do need the `paint` gem installed, from rubygems: `gem install paint`

Update:

Thanks to [manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork) for the much shorter:

```
require'paint';['#0057b7','#ffd700'].map{|c|5.times{puts Paint[?█*37,c]}}
```

Original attempt (127 bytes):

```
require'paint';c=['#0057b7','#ffd700'];(0..1).each do |i|;(0..4).each do;(0..36).each do;print Paint['█',c[i]];end;puts;end;end
```

[image: console output of Ukrainian flag from code.]

Comment: Nice try, but not really matches the goal of [tag:code-golf] challenges. May I suggest the mostly equivalent `require'paint';['#0057b7','#ffd700'].map{|c|5.times{puts Paint[?█*37,c]}}`?

Comment: Thanks @manatwork! I haven't used Ruby in a bit, but that's much shorter.

Comment: You can use a word array to save 2 bytes 
`require'paint';%w(#0057b7 #ffd700).map{|c|5.times{puts Paint[?█*37,c]}}`

Answer (score 5):

## Lua + LÖVE, 154 characters

```lua
l=love
g=l.graphics
c=255
l.window.setMode(78,52)function l.draw()g.setBackgroundColor(0,87/c,183/c)g.setColor(1,215/c,0)g.rectangle("fill",0,26,78,52)end
```

Sample output:

[image: flag of Ukraina]

Answer (score 5):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com) + `viewmat`, 33 bytes

```
viewrgb 52 78$2028#22455 16766720
```

[image]

```
viewrgb 52 78$2028#22455 16766720
              2028#22455 16766720  NB. repeat color values 26*78 times
        52 78$                     NB. shape that into a matrix
viewrgb                            NB. draw the colors
```

### [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 52 bytes

```
viewrgb 52 78$22455,&:(2028&$)16766720[load'viewmat'
```

[image]

```
viewrgb 52 78$22455,&:(2028&$)16766720[load'viewmat'
                                       load'viewmat'  : loads the lib into the session
                                      [               : acts as a statement seperator
              22455,&:(2028&$)16766720                : array of color values
                   ,&:(2028&$)                        : append,appose,shape bonded with
                                                      : 2028 as the left arg which
                                                      : invokes shape on the two args
                                                      : individually and invokes append
                                                      : on the results
        52 78$                                        : creates the color matrix
viewrgb                                               : draw the colors
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Octave](https://octave.org/), 55 bytes

```
imagesc([5 5 5;4 4 4],climits=[3,5])
colormap(prism(5))
```

[image]

My first time posting in Octave! There might be a way to display without having to use `climits`, or maybe even without changing the default colormap, but I have not found it yet.

Answer (score 5):

## ARM Thumb machine code, Game Boy Advance, 36 bytes

```
04 20 00 06 05 49 01 80 48 06 09 0c 44 18 04 4a
13 0c 89 1e 42 52 63 52 fb d1 fe e7 03 04 00 96
40 59 5f 03
```

Thumb function that runs at a 4 byte aligned address.

[image: ok the colors are actually a bit darker due to the GBA's messed up gamma]

Assembler source:

```c
    .syntax unified
    .arch armv4t
    .globl ukraine
    .thumb
    .thumb_func
    // Runs at a 4 byte aligned address
    .p2align 2,0
ukraine:
    // 0x04000000 = REG_DISPCNT
    movs    r0, #0x04
    lsls    r0, r0, #24
    // Load packed halfword constants
    ldr     r1, consts
    // REG_DISPCNT = MODE_3 | BG2_ENABLE
    // Set to display mode 3, enable BG2 layer
    strh    r1, [r0]
    // r0 = 0x...0403 << 25 = 0x06000000 = VRAM address
    lsls    r0, r1, #25
    // Shift in loop counter/offset (0x9600)
    lsrs    r1, r1, #16
    // r4 = 0x06009600 = second half of screen
    adds    r4, r0, r1
    // Load packed colors
    ldr     r2, colors
    // Unpack
    lsrs    r3, r2, #16
    // Double memset16 loop
.Lloop:
    // Decrement counter, set flags
    subs    r1, r1, #2
    // Store blue
    strh    r2, [r0, r1]
    // Store yellow
    strh    r3, [r4, r1]
    // Loop while not 0
    bne     .Lloop
    // Idle spin
.Lspin:
    b       .Lspin

    .p2align 2,0
consts:
    // MODE_3 | BG2_ENABLE
    // Also used for vram address
    .hword  0x0403
    // Half of the screen in halfwords
    .hword  240 * (160 / 2) * 2

    // Converts r8, g8, b8 to RGB5
    .macro RGB8 r, g, b
        .hword  ((\r >> 3) << 0)  | ((\g >> 3) << 5) | ((\b >> 3) << 10)
    .endm

colors:
    RGB8    0, 87, 183   // blue
    RGB8    255, 215, 0  // yellow
```

This function switches the GBA to display mode 3, where VRAM is treated as a flat bitmap of 16-bit RGB5 pixels. This is the easiest to manipulate as there is no need for tilemaps or palettes, I can just fill VRAM with colors.

Answer (score 5):

## Game Boy Color assembly, <s>99</s> 97 bytes

Must be placed at $0150, to which it is jumped from $0100 (standard Game Boy stuff).

```
0E 40 3C E0 41 E6 02 E0 FF 76 F2 CB BF E2 3E 80
E0 68 21 69 FF AF 36 60 36 59 77 77 77 77 36 5F
36 03 3E 40 06 02 21 00 98 CD AB 01 3E 20 06 00
CD AB 01 AF 57 04 CD AB 01 04 CD AB 01 3E 10 42
26 80 CD AB 01 3E 20 06 FF CD AB 01 3E 30 70 23
72 23 BD 20 F9 F2 CB FF E2 18 FE 70 23 BD 20 FB
C9
```

Disassembly:

```
ROMCode:
    ld c, $40
; first we turn off the LCD so the LCD doesn't tell our mother[board] that it's their turn to access the VRAM

; wait for LCD Status to be at vblank to avoid hardware damage
; removing this "saves" eight bytes
; this is also our non-CGB/GBA/SGB2 filter: those will hang, because the way their A register is initialized, this will put them in an endless halt
.vblankWait:
    inc a ; on CGB and compatible, A is initialized to $11. in fact, that is how software is supposed to detect CGB compatibility.
    ldh [$ff41], a
    and $02
    ldh [$ffff], a
    db $76 ; halt. saves byte over "halt", which auto-inserts nop
           ; if you do this in a project, beware the halt bug.

; turn off the LCD
    ldh a, [c]
    res 7, a
    ldh [c], a

; now we fill the palette.

; the palette ram is indirectly accessed using a control register with an address and auto-increment bit and a data register
    ld a, $80
    ldh [$ff68], a
    ld hl, $ff69
    xor a

    ld [hl], $60
    ld [hl], $59
rept 4
    ld [hl], a
endr
    ld [hl], $5f
    ld [hl], $03

; now we fill the tile map.
    ld a, $40
    ld b, 2
    ld hl, $9800
    call FillWithB

    ld a, $20
    ld b, 0
    call FillWithB

    xor a
    ld d, a ; for later
    inc b
    call FillWithB

    inc b
    call FillWithB

; and now we have tile 0 be all color 0b00, tile 1 be all color 0b11, and tile 2 be all color 0b10
    ld a, $10
    ld b, d
    ld h, $80
    call FillWithB
    
    ld a, $20
    ld b, $ff
    call FillWithB

    ld a, $30
.fillTwoValues:
    ld [hl], b
    inc hl
    ld [hl], d
    inc hl
    cp l
    jr nz, .fillTwoValues

; turn on the LCD
    ldh a, [c]
    set 7, a
    ldh [c], a

; and now that we're done let's spin.
    jr @

FillWithB:
    ld [hl], b
    inc hl
    cp l
    jr nz, FillWithB
    ret
```

[image: demonstration on BGB]

Game Boy Color colors are wonky. It's also 10:7, but that's close enough to 3:2.

Edit 1: Missed completing an optimization I had already partially done (`ldh` with `[c]`). -2 bytes.

Edit 2: More safe vblank wait code. No size change.

Edit 3: Edit 2 broke the second halt, which is now replaced with an infinite spin because fixing it requires more code. No size change, +1 embarrassment from not checking thoroughly enough.

Answer (score 5):

## [Go](https://go.dev), <s>280</s> <s>272</s> 269 bytes

```go
import(."image";c"image/color";d"image/draw";p"image/png";."os")
func f(){N,O,a,b:=NewUniform,d.Src,Rect,d.Draw
F:=NewRGBA(a(0,0,78,52))
b(F,a(0,0,78,26),N(c.RGBA{0,87,183,255}),Point{0,0},O)
b(F,a(0,26,78,52),N(c.RGBA{255,215,0,255}),Point{0,26},O)
p.Encode(Stdout,F)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VVDBSsQwFMRrwX8oOSXwrN1Iu8XiQdF668oufkA2aUvQJiGm7KH0S7wUwZs3_8avMdsWF09v3sybgTfvH40evwzjL6ypwpZJ9dm5-iL7OTuXrdHW4QjJ1mso5zO45PpVW5SLZRWWHVBuls2oBuUR0m-IBHWneFhj0pewAQb765uyOjwrWWvbgoh2lsO24s7De58RFJO-fby7xQzHEMM6g4QSEuxxAX8MTQmUmEfHuz6GbA2r7ApokgwEnrRUzpPxAJuTjaZL0snnz4GuEp_430jTyWmiB8W1qPDOCd05KMgwt_I9vXRsCZOwD_xvwaKM4zx_AQ)

Apparently Go has a (basic) image processing package in the standard library.

Prints the bytes of a 78-by-52px PNG to STDOUT.

#### Changelog

- -12 bytes by @The Thonnu

#### Explanation

```go
import(."image";c"image/color";d"image/draw";p"image/png";."os")
func f(){                                     // boilerplate
B,Y,N,O:=c.RGBA{0,87,183,255},c.RGBA{255,215,0,255},NewUniform,d.Src
// define some useful variables
// - B and Y are RGBA colors
// - d.Src is how the image will be drawn on: Src replaces the pixels of the image with the source image.
F:=NewRGBA(Rect(0,0,78,52))                   // make a new empty RGBA image
d.Draw(F,Rect(0,0,78,26),N(B),Point{0,0},O)   // draw blue on the top half the image
d.Draw(F,Rect(0,26,78,52),N(Y),Point{0,26},O) // draw yellow on the bottom half of the image
p.Encode(Stdout,F)}                           // encode it as a PNG, and send it to STDOUT
```

Comment: [Seems to work without the space after `import`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZC_asMwEMbpqifoaDRJcFUdFTsmJkNN625OSeiQ0Ui2MYklo8pkMH6SLqbQrVvfpk9TJTa00Onuvu_H_Xt7r_T42ebikFeF1-S1-uhseRN9X13XTauNJQzXjfNwLKbkVuijNjiWcylNfsJxO1etqnDMsH7FFJWdEl5JaJ_AHjLYrNaCbZ-S-96HaAmL6A54EAwwiy4HvgjAn9SsOL2outSmAcl2RqB0tXbaGSXbQljiO3IZQcApRZI9uC1ICn8dHlLISELhWdfKuqH-AJv_LA_nNg7e_8I8vNAte1RCy4LsrNSdhZQO04O-LtedH0ao1yN3JpqdcZziDw)

Comment: Also, [you don't need to define `B` and `Y`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZDBSsQwFEVxm5WfULJK4Bk7kXbKFBeK1l1HZvADStKWMjYJMWUWpV_ipgju3Pk3fo2ZtqDi6r37LvfAfa9vtR4_TCEORV0GbdGo985VF8nX2XnTGm0dYbhpvYdTMS-XQj9ri1O5SGmLI07NooyqccqwfsEUVZ0SQUVon8N2c52XxyfVVNq2INneCpRNt93D7Q3ZlcKREEJYJxBxSpFkdx5LMvjt8JhCTgQ7RfoQkjWskivgUTRQeNSNcv4YDrD9H-fxQv7J-xjwVeTJfwE8ngiG3SuhZUn2TurOQUaH-TGfU6vTowgNeuTrocUZx3l-Aw)

Comment: [Another -2](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VVDBSsQwFMRrwX8oOSXwrN1Iu8XiQdF668oufkA2aUvQJiGm7KH0S7wUwZs3_8avMdsWF09v3sybgTfvH40evwzjL6ypwpZJ9dm5-iL7OTuXrdHW4QjJ1mso5zO45PpVW5SLZRWWHVBuls2oBuUR0m-IBHWneFhj0pewAQb765uyOjwrWWvbgoh2lsO24s7De58RFJO-fby7xQzHEMM6g4QSEuxxAX8MTQmUmEfHuz6GbA2r7ApokgwEnrRUzpPxAJuTjaZL0snnz4GuEp_430jTyWmiB8W1qPDOCd05KMgwt_I9vXRsCZOwD_xvwaKM4zx_AQ)

Answer (score 4):

## [Node](https://nodejs.org/) JavaScript <s>84</s>,  <s>83</s>, <s>77</s>, 66

**83 bytes**

```
f=n=>`\x1b[48;5;${n}m${' '.repeat(78)}\x1b[m
`.repeat(13);console.log(f(33)+f(220))
```

draws the flag on terminal output, 1 byte saved thanks to   @Samathingajig's suggestion to use an inline LF instead of '\n'.

You can try copying and pasting the code after the REPL prompt (brought up by running node in a terminal). Alternatively save the code to file and run it with `node filename`.

**77 bytes**

Another 6 bytes saved by replacing each occurence of `\x1b` (4bytes) with a single ASCII ESC character (1 byte). Due to character set limitations in HTML, you can *run the code snippet* to see the actual code and length. Save it to file and run with Node to see the flag:

```js
js.value="f=n=>`\x1b[48;5;${n}m${' '.repeat(78)}\x1b[m\n`.repeat(13);console.log(f(33)+f(220))"
console.log("Length=%s", js.value.length);
```

```html
<textarea id="js" style="width:90%"></textarea>

<!-- Click on Run Code Snippet to see the code-->
```

- Run the 77 byte version as a file:

  Raw ANSI color escapes in pasted source appear to be filtered out (sanitized?) before node's REPL prompt echoes or evaluates code, resulting in no flag being drawn.
- [Ansi 8-bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#8-bit) color codes were used because [24 bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#24-bit)  codes were not effective in terminals tested.
- Tested in linux terminal and Windows CMD.exe terminal. GitHub's bash terminal for windows used Cyan and Yellow instead of the colors specified.
- The 3:2 aspect ratio is approximate and may vary according to the font metrics of the terminal font.

[image]

---

**flag.js (66 bytes)**

```
f=h=>`${h[0].repeat(78)}
`.repeat(26)
console.log(f``+f``)
```

- Run from file in node and redirect `stdout` to a text file

  ```
    node flag > flag.txt
  ```
- Load the text file in a browser with dark mode selected (preferably).

To preview run the following code snippet (it has an additional line to provide a "console.log" functions to mimic writing to `stdout`), full screen the snippet window and reduce page zoom as required to make the flag fit within the window.

```js
console.log = s=> document.querySelector('code').textContent+=s;

f=h=>`${h[0].repeat(78)}
`.repeat(26)
console.log(f``+f``)
```

```css
pre, code{height: 100%; width: 100%; background:black}
```

```html
<pre><code></code></pre>
```

Comment: You can replace `\n` with the literal newline character to save 1 byte, since template literals allow for multiline strings

Comment: @Samathingamajig Hi - and thanks again. I actually came across that when testing changing `\x1b` to `ESC` characters but "fixed" it to go back to `\n` without realizing it would be valid(LOL). Now at 77 bytes, best...

Comment: "This now needs to be saved to a file in order to run with Node - the linefeed was not parsed correctly when pasted after the REPL prompt." [It works for me when I just paste it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPn8Z.png). I guess it depends on the terminal/OS (the 83 byte version)

Comment: @Samathingamajig Interesting:  I've had it error using CMD.exe terminal but it worked when retested. Ming64 terminal (GitHub"s bash terminal for windows) failed once but worked after a retry. I'd say "results may vary" without being sure if it was me or the computer. Both of these terminals (or REPL code)  filter out the ANSI color escape sequences from input when pasting the 77 byte code into the terminal, without echoing the sequences on the command line or using them during evaluation.

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, <strike>83</strike> <strike>81</strike> 69 bytes

My first haskell submission.

This code defines a function that prints the flag to stdout using ansi escape codes.

```hs
n?s=[1..n]>>s
putStr$"43">>= \c->13?(78?("\27[4"++c:"m \27[m")++"\n")
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

### PHP Imagick (209 chars)

Draw and output the image to the browser ([Imagick](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.imagick.php) is a native PHP extension).
No line break are needed for execution :

```php
header('Content-Type:image/png');
$d=new\ImagickDraw();
$d->setFillColor('#0057B7');
$d->rectangle(0,0,990,330);
$i=new\Imagick();
$i->newImage(990,660,'#FFD700');
$i->setImageFormat('png');
$i->drawImage($d);
echo$i;
```

[image: Programming Golf Ukrainian Flag with PHP Imagick]

Answer (score 4):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 39 bytes

```
99*:3*&s*:[r009r,]+[r990r,]+'Po9lf2*f3r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/9/SUsvKWEutWMsqusjAwLJIJ1Y7usjS0gDEUA/It8xJM9JKMy76/x8A)

This code pushes RGB values compatible with PPM ASCII formatted image into the stack, then creates a minimum PPM header before exiting. The numbers on the stack are printed automatically when the code exits.

```
Generate width/height numbers, figure out "half the pixels" count

 99*         - Push "81" on stack (will be 1/2 height, 1/3 width)
    :        - Duplicate top of stack
     3*      - Multiple by 3 (yields width)
       &s    - Save stack to backup (needed later for header)
         *   - Multiple to get "half the pixels"
          :  - Duplicate top of stack

Generate blue pixels, pushed onto the stack

 [      ]+  - Loops one per pixel
  r         - Reverse stack
   009      - Push "0 0 9" onto stack
      r     - Reverse to get pixel count back to top
       ,    - Decrement counter

Generate yellow pixels, pushed onto the stack

 [      ]+  - Loops once per pixel
  r         - Reverse stack
   990      - Push "9 9 0" onto stack
      r     - Reverse to get pixel count back to top
       ,    - Decrement counter

Print PPM header

 'Po          - Print "P"
    9         - Push 9 as "max RGB value"
     l        - Load "width and height" from backup cell
      f       - Flip top two entries (width, height)
       2*     - Double to get the height
         f    - Flip top two entries back
          3   - Push 3, the "PPM image type"
           r  - Reverse stack, stack prints automatically
```

Answer (score 4):

## BBC BASIC, 72 bytes

```
V. 19,0,16,255,215|25,97,78;26;25,4,78;27;19,0,16,0,87,183;25,97,-78;26;
```

### Output

[image: Output]

Answer (score 4):

## Python + Pygame (122 bytes)

```py
import pygame.display as p
s=p.set_mode((78,52))
s.fill((0,87,183),(0,0,78,26))
s.fill((255,215,0),(0,26,78,26))
p.flip()
```

Briefly flashes the flag on the screen before exiting.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## C# (.NET Framework), 163 chars

Shorter version of [Björn Larsson's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246187/76508).

```
void Draw(){var f=new Bitmap(78,52);for(int y=0;y<52;y++)for(int x=0;x<78;x++)f.SetPixel(x,y,Color.FromArgb(y>25?255:0,y>25?215:87,y>25?0:183));f.Save("f.bmp");}
```

Effective version with explanation:

```
using System.Drawing;

namespace Ukraine {
    internal class Program {
        static void Main() {
            // Create a bitmap.
            var f = new Bitmap(78, 52);

            // Iterate over the bitmap's pixels.
            for (int y = 0; y < 52; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < 78; x++) {
                    f.SetPixel(                  // Set the pixel...
                        x, y,                    // at the current x and y...
                        Color.FromArgb(
                            y > 25 ? 255 : 0,    // selecting the R value with a ternary expression...
                            y > 25 ? 215 : 87,   // selecting the G value with a ternary expression...
                            y > 25 ? 0 : 183)    // and selecting the B value with a ternary expression.
                        );
                }
            }

            // Save the bitmap.
            f.Save("f.bmp");
        }
    }
}
```

Produces an image in the exe's folder:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! One thing to note is that snippets are [not allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2422/107299) by our rules, so you would have to wrap this in a full program (all the `Main` stuff and whatnot).

Comment: A function would also be allowed

Comment: @Seggan C# supports top-level code nowadays.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (Node.js), 94 bytes

Prints a solid flag (or not quite, depending on your font) in the specified rgb colors.

```js
for(i=1;i<4108;i++)process.stdout.write(i%79?`\x1b[38;2;${i<2054?'0;87;183':'255;215;0'}m█`:`
`)
```

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby with Shoes, 96 characters

```ruby
Shoes.app(width:78,height:52){background rgb 0,87,183
stroke fill rgb 255,215,0
rect 0,26,78,52}
```

Sample output:

[image: flag of Ukraina]

Answer (score 4):

## FLTK, 153 characters

```
Function{}{}{Fl_Window{}{xywh{9 9 78 52}}{Fl_Box{}{xywh{0 0 78 26}box FLAT_BOX color 0x0057b7ff}Fl_Box{}{xywh{0 26 78 52}box FLAT_BOX color 0xffd700ff}}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
Function {} {} {
    Fl_Window {} {
        xywh {9 9 78 52}
    } {
        Fl_Box {} {
            xywh {0 0 78 26}
            box FLAT_BOX
            color 0x0057b7ff
        }
        Fl_Box {} {
            xywh {0 26 78 52}
            box FLAT_BOX
            color 0xffd700ff
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output:

[image: flag of Ukraina]

Answer (score 4):

## [C (MSVC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B) + Win32, 106 bytes

```c
r[4];p(c){FillRect(GetDC(0),r,CreateSolidBrush(c));}main(){*r=600;r[1]=200;p(12344064);r[3]=400;p(55039);}
```

Draws the flag onto the top window:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

## Python (Thonny 4.0 REPL), 419 bytes

```
print("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAARMAAAC3CAMAAAAGjUrGAAAAD1BMVEUAW7v/1QAAVb+ln3n/2QAG3wIgAAAAzUlEQVR4nO3QsQGAMAzAsBT4/2b2eO0onaAZAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACASx62ednmY5vD5qSclJNyUk7KSTkpJ+WknJSTclJOykk5KSflpJyUk3JSTspJOSkn5aSclJNyUk7KSTkpJ+WknJSTclJOykk5KSflpJyUk3JSTspJOSkn5aSclJNyUk7KSTkpJ+WknJSTclJOykk5KSflpJyUk3JSTspJOSkn5aSclJNyUk7KSTkpJ+WknJSTclJOykk5KSflpH7zk2pa0LCuDAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==")
```

Longer than a standard answer but ok. Thonny supports printing images if they’re in base64 form.

[image]

Comment: Your first answer is valid, if a little long (although I'd change the title to something like "Python 3 (Thonny REPL), 419 bytes"; your second answer isn't valid as it's not actually a program which outputs the image. (And the image isn't correctly formatted anyway.)

Answer (score 4):

## [Pikchr](https://pikchr.org/home/doc/trunk/homepage.md), <s>52 51</s> 48 bytes

```
up
box ht.25color-1fill gold
box same fill 22455
```

### Output

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 112.32 76.32">
<path d="M2,74L110,74L110,38L2,38Z" style="fill:rgb(255,215,0);"></path>
<path d="M2,38L110,38L110,2L2,2Z" style="fill:rgb(0,87,183);"></path>
</svg>
```

### Explanation

- `up`: The objects will be laid out from bottom to top.
- `box`: Draws a box (rectangle).
- `ht .25`: The box will be 0.25 inches tall. The default box width is 0.75 inches, which gives us the desired ratio of 3:1.
- `color -1`: The box will have no outline.
- `fill gold`: The box will be colored using the standard HTML color `gold`, which happens to be the color of the yellow stripe.
- `box`: Draws another box.
- `same`: The box will inherit all properties from the previous object.
- `fill 22455`: The number is `57B7` in hexadecimal, so the color of the box will be `#0057B7`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 26.5 bytes (53 nibbles)

```
"P3 78 52 255 ".\`\~`D256^2028$ FFD7000057B7
```

Outputs a plain PPM file of 78x52 pixels, depicting the Ukrainian flag using exact colours.

```
"P3 78 52 255 "         # prepend the string "P3 78 52 255 " onto:
     `D256              # extract data in base 256,
  `\~                   # and divide into 2 chunks,
 \                      # reverse them,
.                       # and map over each
          ^2028$        # repeating it 2028 times. 
FFD7000057B7            # The data.
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

## Minecraft Function, 58 Bytes

```
fill 1 1 1 78 26 1 yellow_bed
fill 1 27 1 78 52 1 blue_bed
```

Creates the Ukrainian flag using blue and yellow beds. Go to the coordinates `0, 0, 0` and it should be visible. I recommend running it in a flat/superflat world with version 1.18 or later.

### Image

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## [Prism](https://codeberg.org/kevidryon2/prism) v0.2a, 5 bytes

Prism is a small esolang I developed in the last couple of days.

It's not (yet) available as a pre-compiled executable, so you'll have to compile it yourselves to test this program.

Anyway, since 80% of the bytes in this program aren't printable characters, here is a hexdump of the program, made with `xxd -g 1`:

```
00000000: c0 aa 58 02 9e                                   ..X..
```

The program does two things:

1. It resizes the canvas and the window from the default 256x256 to 256x170;
2. It draws two horizontal stripes with 4-bit colors `9` and `e`.

As of version 0.2a, Prism only supports 4-bit colors, and thus I picked the two aforementioned colors as they were the closest available.

You can run this program (or any other Prism program) by using `prism draw <filename>`.

[image: result]

Answer (score 4):

## Actionscript 3, <s>94</s> 89 bytes

Here comes our national flag in Actionscript and this is my first submission in this language, since my usual languages have been already taken. The code throws an error, but it will compile a SWF anyway. I took the inspiration from an answer to [another challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64140/draw-the-national-flag-of-france).

- spared 5 bytes by replacing hexadecimal `0xe0057B7` for `22455` and `0xeffd700` for `16766720`.

`var g=graphics,f=g.beginFill,r=g.drawRect;f(22455);r(0,0,99,33); f(16766720);r(0,33,99,33)`

[image: Flag 66 x 99 px]

**Glory to Ukraine!**

Answer (score 3):

## HTML, 200 Bytes

```html
<mark style="background-color:blue"id="a"></mark><mark id="b"></mark><script>document.getElementById("a").innerHTML=document.getElementById("b").innerHTML=(" ".repeat(78)+"<br>").repeat(26)</script>
```

Those poor Ukrainians...

You should click on the link to render the full page after running the code.

Prints the Ukrainian flag (although it's missing a trident unfortunately) using `<mark>` tags to render the colours. Uses a script to insert the text. Uses `U+2001 EM QUAD` as a blank character.

Comment: You can use `background` in place of `background-color`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Chipmunk BASIC](http://www.nicholson.com/rhn/basic/), 116 bytes

Chipmunk Basic v368b2.02 on MacOS. This fun wee lang adjusts RGB values by a factor`0.392157`.

```
graphics 0
graphics color 0,34,72
graphics fillrect 0,0,132,44
graphics color 100,84,0
graphics fillrect 0,44,132,88
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 34 bytes

```
&ims÷255⊂∩(↯26_78_3)0_87_183 255_215_0
```

[Try it in the pad!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__Jmltc8O3MjU14oqC4oipKOKGrzI2Xzc4XzMpMF84N18xODMgMjU1XzIxNV8wCg==)

### Explanation

`0_87_183 255_215_0`: Push the RGB values on the stack

`∩(…)`: Apply this function to both values:

- `↯26_78_3`: Reshape them so they become stripes

`&ims÷255⊂`: Join them together and divide by 255, then show as an image

Answer (score 1):

## SVG - [Scalable Vector Graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG). 151 bytes

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 3 2"><path d="M0 0H3V1H0ZM0 1H3V2H0Z" fill="#005BBB"/><path d="M0 1H3V2H0Z" fill="#FFD500"/></svg>
```

[Try it online](https://svgur.com/i/14cD.svg)